# If $a \mid m$ and $(a + 1) \mid m$, prove $a(a + 1) | m$.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Can anyone help me out here? Can't seem to find the right rules of divisibility to show this:

If $a \mid m$ and $(a + 1) \mid m$, then $a(a + 1) \mid m$.

Comment: Remember that $a$ and $a+1$ are relatively prime: this will do it!

Comment: Thanks! Is that... recommended for an exam?

Comment: I don't understand Chandru1's comment: he shows that $a(a+1)$ divides $m^2$.  We want to show that it divides $m$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not surprising that you are finding this difficult, because it goes beyond basic divisibility rules -- it rather requires something which is essentially equivalent to the uniqueness of prime factorization.  [**Edit**: Actually this is comment is incorrect -- as Robin Chapman's answer shows, it *is* possible to prove this using just divisibility rules.  In particular it is true in any integral domain.]

I assume $a$ and $m$ are positive integers.  The first observation is that $a$ and $a+1$ are relatively prime: i.e., there is no integer $d > 1$ -- or equivalently, no prime number-- which divides both $a$ and $a+1$, for then $d$ would have to divide $(a+1) - a = 1$, so $d = 1$.

Now the key step: since $a$ divides $m$, we may write $m = aM$ for some positive integer $M$.  So $a+1$ divides $aM$ and is relatively prime to $a$.  **I claim** that this implies $a+1$ divides $M$.  Assuming this, we have $M = (a+1)N$, say, so altogether

$m = aM = a(a+1)N$, so $a(a+1)$ divides $m$.

The claim is a special case of:

(Generalized) Euclid's Lemma: Let $a,b,c$ be positive integers.  Suppose $a$ divides $bc$ and $a$ is relatively prime to $b$.  Then $a$ divides $c$.

A formal proof of this requires some work!  See for instance

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)

In particular, proving this is essentialy as hard as proving the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Comment: Thanks, that was fast. I see the logic now :D Just hope I can replicate this in my exam tomorrow!

Comment: @Pete: I just realized that you removed the tag "divison-algebra" and that probably that tag should be "division-algebra": is there a way to correct the spelling of the tag?

Comment: @damiano: my understanding is that only a moderator can delete tags.  But we can certainly add the tag with the correct spelling and make sure that it is the correct tag which actually appears in questions (when appropriate).

Comment: I have retagged the unique question that had "divison-algebra" to "division-algebra". Now there are the two tags available, but, as you say, we should wait for the misspelled tag to be removed by a moderator.

Comment: About the Edit: I think Robin shows this. If, in a ring, $m$ and $m+1$ divide $a$ on the left, so does $m(m+1)$. No use of the absence of zero divisors or of the commutativity seems to be made.

Comment: @PYG: Yes, that's true.  I just prefer to think of divisibility in the context of integral domains.

Comment: In some sense Robin's answer is better than yours, but in another sense yours is better, the interesting question being: When are the common multiples of two integers the multiples of their product? If you know that Z is an UFD, this is trivial. If you don't know that, and you're interested in math, you should learn it. [This is basically what you said.] [All the answers to this question are excellent.]

Answer (score 68):

The other answers put this in a general context, but in this example one
can be absolutely explicit. If $a\mid m$ and $(a+1)\mid m$ then there are
integers $r$ and $s$ such that
$$m=ar=(a+1)s.$$
Then
$$a(a+1)(r-s)=(a+1)[ar]-a[(a+1)s]=(a+1)m-am=m.$$
As $r-s$ is an integer, then $a(a+1)\mid m$.

Comment: Do the brackets in $[ar]$ have special meaning?

Comment: I would have said \begin{array}{rcr}
    a(a+1)r &=& (a+1)m\\
    a(a+1)s &=& am\\ \hline
    a(a+1)(r-s) &=& m
\end{array}

Comment: **Proof:** Suppose that $a \mid m$ and $a + 1 \mid m$, where $a$ and $m$ are integers. Therefore, there exist integers $r$ and $s$ such that (1) $ar = m$ and (2) $(a + 1)s = m$. Multiplying (1) by $a + 1$, we get $a(a + 1)r = (a + 1)m$ (3). Multiplying (2) by $a$, we get $a(a + 1)s = am$ (4). Now subtracting (3) and (4), we get $$a(a + 1)r - a(a + 1)s = (a + 1)m - am$$ $$\Rightarrow a(a + 1)(r - s) = m$$ And Since $r - s$ is an integer, we have that $$a(a + 1) \mid m$$. $Q.E.D.$

Answer (score 33):

> If  $\rm\,\ a\mid m,\ a\!+\!1\mid m\ \,$ then it follows that $\rm\ \, \color{#90f}{a(a\!+\!1)\mid m}$

${\bf Proof}\rm\quad\displaystyle \frac{m}{a},\; \frac{m}{a+1}\in\mathbb{Z} \ \,\Rightarrow\,\ \frac{m}{a} - \frac{m}{a\!+\!1} \; = \;\color{#90f}{\frac{m}{a(a\!+\!1)} \in \mathbb Z}.\quad$ **QED**

${\bf Remark}\rm\ \, \text{More generally, if }\, \color{#c00}{n = bc \:\!-\:\! ad} \;$ is a linear combination of $\rm\, a, b\, $ then

$\rm\text{we have}\quad\,\ \displaystyle \frac{m}{a},\; \frac{m}{b}\in\mathbb{Z} \;\;\Rightarrow\;\; \frac{m}{a}\frac{\color{#c00}{bc}}{b} - \frac{\color{#c00}{ad}}{a}\frac{m}{b} = \frac{m\:\!\color{#c00}n}{a\:\!b} \in \mathbb Z$

By Bezout, $\rm\, \color{#c00}{n = \gcd(a,b)}\, $  is the *least* positive linear combination, so the above yields

$\rm\qquad\qquad a,b\mid m \;\Rightarrow\; ab\mid m\;gcd(a,b) \;\Rightarrow\; \mathfrak{m}_{a,b}\!\mid m\ \ $  for $\ \ \rm \mathfrak{m}_{a,b} := \dfrac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$

i.e. $ $ every common multiple $\rm\, m\,$ of $\,\rm a,b\,$ is a multiple of $\;\rm \mathfrak{m}_{a,b},\,$ so $\rm\, \color{#0a0}{\mathfrak{m}_{a,b}\le m}.\,$ But $\rm\,\mathfrak{m}_{a,b}\,$ is also a *common* multiple, i.e. $\rm\ a,b\mid \mathfrak{m}_{a,b}\,$ viz. $\displaystyle \,\rm \frac{\mathfrak{m}_{a,b}}{a} = \;\frac{a}{a}\frac{b}{gcd(a,b)}\in\mathbb Z\,$ $\,\Rightarrow\,$ $\rm\, a\mid \frak{m}_{a,b},\,$ and  $\,\rm b\mid \mathfrak{m}_{a,b}\,$ by symmetry. Thus  $\,\rm \mathfrak{m}_{a,b} = lcm(a,b)\,$ is the $\rm\color{#0a0}{least}$ common multiple of $\rm\,a,b.\,$ In fact we have proved the stronger statement that it is a common multiple that is *divisibility-least*, i.e. it divides every common multiple. This is the general definition of LCM in an arbitrary domain (ring without zero-divisors), i.e. we have the following **universal** dual definitions of LCM and GCD, which essentially says that LCM & GCD are $\,\sup\,$ & $\,\inf\,$ in the poset induced by divisibility order $\,a\preceq b\!\iff\! a\mid b$.

**Definition** of **LCM** $\ \ $ If $\quad\rm a,b\mid c\,\iff\; d\mid c \ \ \,$ then $\rm\ d\approx lcm(a,b)$
compare: $\, $ **Def** of $\rm\,\cap\ \ \,$ If $\rm\ \ \ a,b\supset c\iff d\supset c\,\ $ then $\,\ \rm d = a\cap b$

**Definition** of **GCD** $\ \ $ If $\quad\rm c\mid a,b \;\iff\; c\mid d \,\ $ then $\,\ \rm d \approx \gcd(a,b)$
compare: $\, $ **Def** of $\rm\,\cup\ \ \,$ If $\rm\ \ \ c\supset a,b\iff c\supset d\,\ $ then $\,\ \rm d = a\cup b$

Note  $\;\rm a,b\mid [a,b] \;$ follows by putting $\;\rm c = [a,b] \;$ in the definition. $ $ Dually $\;\rm (a,b)\mid a,b$.

Above $\rm\,d\approx e\,$ means $\rm\,d,e\,$ are associate, i.e. $\rm\,d\mid e\mid d\,$ (equivalently $\rm\,d = u\!\: e\,$ for $\,\rm u\,$ a unit = invertible). In general domains gcds are defined only up to associates (unit multiples), but we can often *normalize* to rid such unit factors, e.g. normalizing the gcd to be $\ge 0$ in $\Bbb Z,\,$ and making it monic for polynomials over a field, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2939562/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3009888/242).

Such universal definitions enable slick unified proofs of both arrow directions, e.g.

**Theorem**  $\rm\;\; (a,b) = ab/[a,b] \;\;$  if $\;\rm\ [a,b] \;$  exists.

**Proof**:  $\rm\quad d\mid a,b \iff a,b\mid ab/d \iff [a,b]\mid ab/d \iff\ d\mid ab/[a,b] \quad$ **QED**

The conciseness of the proof arises by exploiting to the hilt the $\:\!(\!\!\iff\!\!)\:\!$ definition of LCM, GCD.  Implicit in the above proof is an innate cofactor duality. Brought to  the fore, it clarifies LCM, GCD duality (analogous to DeMorgan's Laws), e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/717775/242) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2127538/242)

By the theorem, GCDs exist if LCMs exist. But common multiples clearly comprise an ideal, being closed under subtraction and multiplication by any ring element. Hence in a PID the generator of an ideal of common multiples is clearly an LCM. In Euclidean domains this can be proved directly by a simple descent, e.g. in $\:\mathbb Z \;$ we have the following [high-school level proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242) of the existence of LCMs (and, hence, of GCDs), after noting the set $\rm M$ of common multiples of $\rm a,b$ is closed under subtraction and contains $\:\rm ab \ne 0\:$:

**Lemma** $\ $ If $\;\rm M\subset\mathbb Z \;$ is closed under subtraction and $\rm M$ contains a nonzero element $\rm\,k,\,$ then $\rm M \:$ has a positive element and the least such positive element of $\;\rm M$ divides every element.

**Proof** $\, $ Note $\rm\, k-k = 0\in M\,\Rightarrow\, 0-k = -k\in M, \;$ therefore $\rm M$ contains a positive element.  Let $\rm\, m\,$ be the least positive element in $\rm\, M.\,$ Since $\,\rm m\mid n \iff m\mid -n, \;$ if some $\rm\, n\in M\,$ is not divisible by $\,\rm m\,$ then we
may assume that $\,\rm n > 0,\,$ and the least such. Then $\rm\,M\,$ contains $\rm\, n-m > 0\,$  also not divisible by $\rm m,\,$ and smaller than $\rm n$, contra leastness of $\,\rm n.\ \ $ **QED**

Comment: Do I understand it right that $\mathrm{gcd}:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is right adjoint of the diagonal function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, if $\mathbb{Z}$ is ordered by the `divisibility' relation?

Comment: @Egbert That would make a good question. I recommend that you post it, since it wouldn't get much exposure buried here in the comments. Was your question sparked by my recent [answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147771/rewriting-repeated-integer-division-with-multiplication/147832#147832) and/or its [link here?](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/6793/242)

Comment: I added the question. Yes, I followed the links in these answers. I find the approach with the universal property illuminating for both my understanding of adjoints and elementary number theory.

Comment: @BillDubuque Can you suggest an article/reference that discusses this category-theoretic view of number theory in detail?

Comment: Note to future readers: The concise (and very nice) proof of the "$\rm\;\; (a,b) = ab/[a,b] \;\;$" theorem requires the implicit understanding that a relation of the form "$u \mid v$" for integer $u$ and rational $v$ means "$v$ is an integer divisible by $u$" (or, equivalently, "$v$ equals $u$ times some an integer"). This matters because the way it is used here, $v$ is not always (a priori) an integer.

Comment: @darij No, the proof does *not* use divisibility of rationals because here $d$ is (implicitly) restricted to divisors of $ab$.  This is clearer when the key involution behind the duality is brought to the fore - for which  see the links I gave in the answer:  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/717775/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1318902/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2127538/242), which emphasize the cofactor involution (reflection) symmetry at the heart of this duality between gcd & lcm.

Answer (score 12):

An alternate route: We show that, if $ax+by=1$ and $m$ is divisible by $a$ and $b$ then $m$ is divisible by $ab$. (Then apply this with $b=a+1$, $x=-1$ and $y=1$.)

**Proof:** Let $m=ak=bl$. Then $ab(xl+ky)=(ax+by)m=m$. QED

The point here is that the hypothesis $\exists_{x,y}: ax+by=1$ is often easier to use than $GCD(a,b)=1$. The equivalence between these two is basically equivalent to unique factorization, and you can often dodge unique factorization by figuring out which of these two you really need.

Comment: Actually it turns out to be simpler to prove by way of GCDs rather than employing the Bezout identity. Namely **A,B|M => AB|AM,BM => AB | (AM,BM) = (A,B) M = M**. This is merely a very special case of the general **LCM, GCD** duality identity. See my post here. Note that this proof works whether one interprets (A,B) as a GCD or as an ideal (as in your Bezout proof). Note that it has the advantage of eliminating obfuscatory info such as the irrelevant variables K,L,X,Y in the Bezout proof.

Comment: I don't want to get into this forever, but I'll try to justify myself. Let's separate two notions of GCD. GCD1(a,b) is the largest integer that divides a and b. GCD2(a,b) is divisible by any integer which divides a and b. The fact that GCD1=GCD2 has some depth; it is basically as hard as unique factorization. (continued...)

Comment: In fact, even the fact that GCD2 is well defined is not obvious. You are clearly using GCD2 when you write ab|am, bm implies ab|(am,bm). (continued)

Comment: Now, the point is, suppose that there exist x and y such that ax+by divides a and divides b. Then ax+by is GCD2(a,b). In this case, we know that GCD2(a,b) exists without ever thinking about the division algorithm or general properties of the larger ring. In particular, the result in question is true in any commutative ring, because we have ax+by=1 for an explicit pair (x,y)=(-1,1). The proof is pure algebraic manipulation, not relying on properties of the integers like GCD2 existing. (continued)

Comment: I should also add that Robin Chapman makes the same points I do much more clearly. In retrospect, it was an expository error to write x and y in place of -1 and 1.

Comment: @David. Part 1: It's not clear what you're trying to justify. The point of my comment to your post is to
emphasize that the (standard) proof that you gave is really just a special case of the more
general approach I gave in my answer. Namely, in my comment, interpreting (A,B) as the ideal A Z + B Z 
yields your answer. Interpreting (A,B) as GCD(A,B) yields the general approach in my answer - which works
for arbitrary cancellative monoids. The two approaches can be unified via divisor theory.

Comment: @David: Part 2: But one doesn't need the generality of divisor theory to exploit such ideas - one simply gives proofs 
using only properties of (A,B) that are enjoyed by both ideals and gcds, e.g. see my unified proof http://bit.ly/FreshGCD  
of the Freshman's Dream (A + B)^n = A^n + B^n that works for both GCDs and invertible ideals. The point is that
working at the natural level of abstraction can be not only more general but also simpler.

Comment: @David: Part 3: I emphasize the **universal** definitions of GCD,LCM for arbitrary cancellative
monoids. This is both more general and more simple. Moreover, it highlights the more fundamental
role played by LCM over GCD.  Even in Z this is evident: common multiples obviously form an
ideal - something already familiar for denominator ideals. Further, the uniqueness / principality
of denominator ideals ("unique fractionization") is already familiar and is essentially
equivalent to unique factorization.  As such its not only more general but also more natural to
begin with LCMs rather than GCDs

Comment: @David: Part 4: You say that "Robin makes the same points", but I don't see any connection between
your post and Robin's. But if you refer to his remark about being "explicit" then one can be even more
so. Namely, see my post where I show that this special case may be inferred by simply subtracting
two integral fractions.  I doubt one can get much more "explicit" than that! Moreover, as I show
very explicitly in my post, such explicit proofs are nothing but specializations of the general result.

Answer (score 0):

If $a|m$ and $a+1|m$ then $lcm(a,a+1)|m$. And we know that $lcm(a,a+1)\cdot gcd(a,a+1) = a(a+1)$ . But $a$ and $(a+1)$ are two consecutive numbers so $gcd(a,a+1)$ $=$ $1$, hence $lcm(a,a+1) = a(a+1)$. So $a(a+1)|m$

Answer (score 0):

If $a | m$ and $(a+1) | m$, prove $a \times (a+1) | m$.
Proof.

By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, $a = p_1^{e_1} \times p_2^{e_2} \times  \dots \times p_t^{e_t}$, where $p_i$ are unique primes, $e_i >= 1$ are natural numbers, and $t = \omega(a)$, the number of unique primes in $a$.

Divide $(a+1)$ by any prime or composite factor of $a$. There will be a remainder of $1$. Therefore, $a$ and $(a+1)$ have no common factors and are relatively prime, $(a,a+1) = 1$.

Since $a | m$, $m$ contains all the factors of $a$, given above. Since $(a+1) | m$, $m$ contains all the factors of $(a+1)$, not shown. Because no factors in $a$ and $(a+1)$ are the same, then $m$ contains all the factors in $a$ and all the factors in $(a+1)$.

Therefore, $a \times (a+1) | m$.

This is an elementary proof, but should be adequate.