# If $\gcd(a,b)=d$, then $\gcd(ac,bc)=cd$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

$A$ an integral domain, $a,b,c\in A$. If $d$ is a greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$, is it true that $cd$ is a greatest common divisor of $ca$ and $cb$? I know it is true if $A$ is a UFD, but can't think of a counterexample in general situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the best that one can say for arbitrary integral domains:

**LEMMA** $\rm\ \ (a,b)\ =\ (ac,bc)/c\quad$  if $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists.

**Proof** $\rm\quad d\ |\ a,b\ \iff\ dc\ |\ ac,bc\ \iff\ dc\ |\ (ac,bc)\ \iff\ d|(ac,bc)/c$

Generally $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ need not exist, as is most insightfully viewed as failure of

**EUCLID'S LEMMA**  $\rm\quad a\ |\ bc\ $ and $\rm\ (a,b)=1\ \Rightarrow\ a\ |\ c\quad$ if $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists.

**Proof** $\ \ $ If $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists then $\rm\ a\ |\ ac,bc\ \Rightarrow\ a\ |\ (ac,bc) = (a,b)\:c = c\ $  by the Lemma.

Therefore if $\rm\: a,b,c\: $ fail to satisfy the Euclid Lemma $\Rightarrow\:$,
namely  if  $\rm\ a\ |\ bc\ $  and  $\rm\ (a,b) = 1\ $  but $\rm\ a\nmid c\:$, then one immediately deduces that the gcd $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ fails to exist. For the special case $\rm\:a\:$ is an atom (i.e. irreducible), the implication reduces to: atom $\Rightarrow$ prime. So it suffices to find a nonprime atom
in order to exhibit a pair of elements whose gcd fails to exist. This task is a bit simpler, e.g. for $\rm\ \omega = 1 + \sqrt{-5}\ \in\ \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\ $ we have that the atom $\rm\: 2\ |\ \omega'\: \omega = 6\:,\:$ but $\rm\ 2\nmid \omega',\:\omega\:,\:$ so $\rm\:2\:$ is not prime. Therefore we deduce that the gcd $\rm\: (2\:\omega,\ \omega'\:\omega)\ =\ (2+2\sqrt{-5},\:6)\ $ fails to exist in $\rm\ \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\:$.

Note that if the gcd $\rm\: (ac,bc)\ $ fails to exist then this implies that the ideal $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ is not principal. Therefore we've *constructively*  deduced that the failure of Euclid's lemma immediately yields both a nonexistent gcd and a nonprincipal ideal.

That the $\Rightarrow$ in Euclid's lemma implies that Atoms are Prime $\rm(:= AP)$ is denoted $\rm\ D\ \Rightarrow AP\ $ in the list of domains closely related to GCD domains in my [post here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/164589/242) There you will find links to further literature on domains closely related to GCD domains. See especially the referenced comprehensive survey by D.D. Anderson: *GCD domains, Gauss' lemma, and contents of polynomials*, 2000.

See also my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m/3149#3149) for the general *universal* definitions of $\rm GCD,\: LCM$ and for further remarks on how such $\iff$ definitions enable slick proofs, and [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-emptyset/3832#3832) for another simple example of such.

Comment: I don't see how this helps.

Comment: @ashpool: I revised it to be more explicit (and more general).

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of your lemma, and my problem is basically showing the existence of (ac,bc).

Comment: Why do you think that such a gcd should exist in an arbitrary domain?

Comment: As a matter of fact I strongly doubt it (existence of (a,b) implying existence of (ac,bc)). That's why I have been trying to find a counterexample.

Comment: I've added remarks on explicit counterexamples by way of Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: @BillDubuque seems the link of your post on google groups is dead.

Comment: @athos Now updated to a local link, thanks.