# Properties of the greatest common divisor and least common multiple

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$, $b$, $c \in \mathbb{N}$. $[a, b]$ denotes $\mathrm{lcm}(a, b)$ and $(a,b)$ denotes $\gcd(a, b)$

Show that

1. $(a,[b,c]) = [(a,b),(a,c)]$.
2. $[a,(b,c)] = ([a,b],[a,c])$.

Comment: Certainly prime factorization works, but it would be nice to see a proof that avoids it.

Comment: These properties say that $\mathbb N$ with the divisor relation is a [distributive lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice).

Comment: as @Srivatsan Narayanan said, it would be nice to see a proof by definition. I donot know if every such properties that is something (equations) about gcd and lcm hold in ufd always hold in a [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gcd_domain) domain?

Answer (score 6):

**HINT** $\ $ Using the basic GCD laws (associative, commutative, [distributive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19830/if-gcd-a-b-1-then-is-it-true-to-say-gcd-ac-bc-c/19842#19842)) and, furthermore,  employing [$\rm\:[x,y] = xy/(x,y)\:$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-emptyset/3832#3832) to eliminate LCMs, we obtain

$$\begin{array}{lrll}
     &\rm(a,[b,c]) &=&\rm [(a,b),(a,c)]&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \\
\iff &\rm(a,bc/(b,c)) &=&\rm (a,b)(c,a)/(a,b,c)& \\
\iff &\rm(a,b,c)(ab,ac,bc) &=&\rm (a,b)(a,c)(b,c)&
\end{array} $$

true since both sides $\rm\: =\: (abc, baa,caa, abb,cbb, acc,bcc)\:$ (i.e. all trinomials except cubes), after expanding, by [distributivity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19830/if-gcd-a-b-1-then-is-it-true-to-say-gcd-ac-bc-c/19842#19842) The dual identity is proved similarly, yielding the same equality.

Comment: Ah of course, $(a,b)(c,d) = (a(c,d),b(c,d)) = ((ac,ad),(bc,bd)) = ((ac,ad),bc,bd) = (ac,ad,bc,bd)$ so you can just multiply them out. I should give up maths for today :(

Comment: @Thi That's why I always stress the GCD laws when teaching. These GCD proofs are all quite trivial once one intuitively grasps that GCD arithmetic is essentially the same as integer arithmetic (modulo a couple GCD-specific laws).  Such axiom-based proofs are more general than proofs depending on primes (UFDs) or the Bezout identity (PIDs), e.g. the same proof often works for gcds and ideals (which is abstracted by *divisor theory*), e.g. the [Freshman's Dream](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10400/comaximal-ideals-in-a-commutative-ring/10416#10416) $\rm\ (A+B)^n\:=\:A^n + B^n$