# Proving that $\gcd(ac,bc)=|c|\gcd(a,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a$, $b$ an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ with $a$ and $b$ not both zero and let $c$ be a nonzero integer. Prove that $$(ca,cb) = |c|(a,b)$$

Comment: Please don't post in the imperative mode, giving orders. If you have a question, then please *ask*.

Answer (score 6):

Below is a proof of the *distributive law* for GCDs that works in every domain.

**THEOREM** $\rm\quad (a,b)\ =\ (ac,bc)/c\quad$  if $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists

**Proof** $\rm\quad d\ |\ a,b\ \iff\ dc\ |\ ac,bc\ \iff\ dc\ |\ (ac,bc)\ \iff\ d|(ac,bc)/c$

See my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16042/about-greatest-common-divisor/16043#16043) for further discussion of this property and its relationship with **Euclid's Lemma**.

Answer (score 4):

Let $d = (ca,cb)$ and $d' = |c|(a,b)$. Show that $d|d'$ and $d'|d$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a,b)=d$, then the equation $ax+by=dz$ has a solution for all $z \in \mathbb{N}$, and this implies that $acx+bcy=(dc)z$ admits a solution for all $z \in \mathbb{N}$. And hence we can deduce the result which must appear in every elementary number theory book.
Moreover, you have not offered your motivation which absolutely will make the post better.