# ring theory - basic question, it seems

Tags: ring-theory

We're in an integral domain with unity 1 $\neq$ 0.  Suppose that the highest common factor between x,y is 1 and the highest common factor for x,z is 1.

Show that $x \mid yz$ implies that $x$ is a unit, or provide a counterexample.

I'm stuck.  I don't have that we are in a unique factorization domain, I don't have that this ring is Noetherian.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the problem wrong :). Just fixed it.

Comment: Did you mean, the highest common factor between $x$ and $y$, and between $x$ and $z$ is $1$? If so, look at $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, $x=2$, $y=1+\sqrt{-5}$, and $z=1-\sqrt{-5}$.

Comment: What does a "highest" common factor mean in a general integral domain (that is, without any assumption that it is Euclidean)?

Comment: (It is probably reasonable to interpret it as "all common factors of $x$ and $y$ are units", or equivalently "the ideal generated by $x$ and $y$ is the entire ring" -- but would be nice to have that confirmed explicitly).

Comment: it means it is a multiple of any other common factor.

Comment: @Henning: It means that it divides both, and anything that divides both will divide it. In the instant case, it just means that the only common factors between them are units.

Comment: @Henning In any ring, $\rm\:gcd(a,b) = 1\:$ means $\rm\:c\:|\:a,b\:\Rightarrow\:c\:|\:1.\:$ This follows from the [universal definition](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) of the gcd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ For the special case $\rm\:x\:$ is irreducible, a counterexample would be an irreducible element that is not prime. These are easy to find in non-UFD number rings. See also [this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16043/242)

Comment: This is interesting.  So then I am clearly stuck on a problem.  I am asked to find that if $a$ and $a$ have a highest common factor, then they have a least common multiple.   So here is my strategy: I let $(a,b)$ be the hcf, write $(a,b)a'=a$ and $(a,b)b'=b$ and claim that my candidate is $(a,b)a'b'$ is my lcm. I will repost this as a new question.