# Are there any integer solutions to $a^3=b^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was wondering if there were any two integers $a$ and $b$ where $a^3=b^2$.

Comment: Did you try to find any? Say, starting with $a=1$?

Comment: Don't forget a = b = 0

Comment: Special case of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065795/gcda-b-1-xa-yb-rightarrow-x-nb-y-na-for-an-integer-n)

Answer (score 21):

Yes. $a=n^2$ and $b=n^3$, where $n$ is any integer. (for example, $n=2$ yields, $a=4$ and $b=8$).

It is actually easy to prove using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic that these are all solutions.

**P.S.** I am really surprised that you missed the obvious solutions: $a=b=0$ and $a=b=1$....

Comment: See my answer for a simple proof that works much more generally.

Comment: @BillDubuque Isn't the proof of the RRT based on the fact that $Z$ is an UFD? Otherwise, how can you speak of reduced fractions and gcd? ;) Nevertheless, nice proof.

Comment: Euclidean $\Rightarrow$ PID $\Rightarrow$ UFD $\Rightarrow$ GCD domain $\Rightarrow$ RRT, integrally-closed, but none of those implications reverse for general integral domains. Hence, for example, the proof I gave works in all quadratic rings of integers, but a proof using unique factorization may not, since such rings generally are not UFDs. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/164589/242) for further discussion.

Comment: @BillDubuque Weird that you would have a solution that works more generally.  I'm just kidding and my joke is a compliment.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\rm\ a=0\!\iff\! b=0.\:$ Else $\rm\:(b/a)^2 = a\in\Bbb Z,\:$ so $\rm\:b/a = n\in\Bbb Z$ via [Rational Root Test (RRT).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) Therefore $\rm\ a = (b/a)^2 = n^2,\:$ so $\rm\:b = an = n^3,\:$ and, indeed, $\rm\:a^3 = (n^2)^3 = (n^3)^2 = b^2\ \ $ **QED**

**Remark** $\ $ Note that the proof did not require unique factorization but only the much weaker Rational Root Test, monic-case. Thus the proof generalizes to any [integrally-closed domain.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrally_closed_domain)

**Update** (to answer questions in comments) Suppose that $\rm\:x^2 - a\:$ has a rational root $\rm\:x = b/a.\:$ Cancelling $\rm\:gcd(a,b)\:$ we can write $\rm\:x = c/d\:$ in lowest terms. Then RRT implies that the denominator divides the lead coef, i.e. $\rm\:d\:|\:1,\:$ so $\rm\:d=\pm1,\:$ so $\rm\: x = c/d = \pm\, c\in \Bbb Z,\:$ hence $\rm\:b/a  = x = c/d\in\Bbb Z.$

Comment: But the Rational Root Test says that $b|-a$ and $a|1$.  So this gives only the solution $a=1,b=1$.  The root test assumes that $(a,b)=1$, so we loose many solutions. Am I right?

Comment: @PantelisDamianou The rational root test is being applied to the roots of $x^2-a=0$, with (for each solution) $x=\frac b a$. We get that $x \in \mathbb Z$ ...

Comment: Exactly. So, $a=1$. But the numerator, which is $b$ should divide the constant term which is $-1$. So, $b=1$.

Comment: @Pantelis, how do you get $a=1$ from knowing $b/a$ is an integer? Isn't $42/6$ an integer? No one said $b/a$ was in lowest terms.

Comment: @Garry Myerson The link you gave says so!

Comment: In any case, the rational root is specific here. It is $\frac{b}{a}$. Therefore the denominator which is $a$ should divide the leading term which is $1$.

Comment: But once you reach $\sqrt{a}=\frac{b}{a}$ you can say: The square root of an integer is rational iff $a$ is a perfect square. Therefore $a=n^2$. Of course, this uses the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: @Pantelis My proof is indeed one of the standard ways to *prove* that well-known result about square-roots. Generally, integrally-closed (monic Rational Root Test) is *weaker* than unique factorization, i.e. UFD $\Rightarrow$ integrally-closed, but the converse fails; e.g. the above proof works in all rings of integers of quadratic number fields $\rm\:\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d}),\:$ which includes infinitely many non-UFDs. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/164589/242) for further discussion.

Comment: @Pantelis, I didn't give any link --- what are you talking about? Anyway, the rational root theorem says the rational **can** be written in such a way that the denominator divides the leading coefficient; it doesn't say that's the *only* way to write the rational. Would you deny that $42/6$ is a root of the polynomial $x-7$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am sorry! I confused you with Bill Dubuque! In his solution he has  a link to a wikipedia article on the Rational root theorem.  The proof in Wikipedia uses the fact that the rational is reduced. I do not object to $\frac{42}{6}$ being a root of $x-7$ but can it be a root of $x^2-6$?  In your example $a=6$ and $b=42$.

Comment: No, but it can be (and is) a root of $x^2-49$. But I'm not sure that I see what we are discussing.

Comment: @Pantelis Suppose that $\rm\:x^2 - a\:$ has a rational root $\rm\:x = b/a.\:$ Cancelling $\rm\:gcd(a,b)\:$ we can write $\rm\:x = c/d\:$ in lowest terms. Then RRT implies that the denominator divides the lead coef, i.e. $\rm\:d\:|\:1,\:$ so $\rm\:d=\pm1,\:$ so $\rm\: x = c/d = \pm\, c\in \Bbb Z,\:$ hence $\rm\:b/a  = x = c/d\in\Bbb Z.$

Comment: QBill Dubuque  o.k. Now I am convinced!

Answer (score 3):

Any number in the form of $n^6$ can be expressed in the desired form so there will be infinite solutions for $a$ and $b$.