# Associates of primes remain prime

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question I'm stuck on is
"Let $R$ be an integral domain and $a, b \in R$ so that $a$ and $b$ are associated.
Show that if $a$ is prime element then $b$ is a prime element."

I don't know how to solve this, like I don't know how to show that an element is a prime element.

Comment: An element $p\in R$ is prime if $\forall a,b \in R.\ p \mid ab \implies p \mid a \lor p\mid b.$ Two elements $p,q\in R$ are associated if $ p \mid q$ and $ q \mid p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $p,q \in R$ associated. Then $p \mid q$ and $q \mid p.$

Suppose $p$ prime.

You have to prove that $(\forall a,b \in R.\ q \mid ab \implies q  \mid a \lor q \mid b).$

Take $a,b\in R$ such that $q \mid ab.$

Since $p \mid q$, you know that $p \mid ab$.

Since $p$ is prime, you know that $p\mid a \lor p \mid b.$

Since $q \mid p$, you know that $q\mid a \lor q \mid b$.

Do the case with $q$ prime and conclude.

Comment: How come p|q and q|p if they're associated? The definition I was given for association just said "If a and b are associated, then there exist a unit c such that a = bc"

Comment: They are equivalent definitions. In particular if there exists a unit $u$ such that $p = qu$, then $q\mid p$. Also, $q=pu^{-1}$, which implies that $p \mid q.$

Comment: Ohh I see! Thank you!

Comment: I've been looking at the proof, but I don't quite understand it, could you elaborate on the steps?

Comment: This cleared things up! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ Divisibility is preserved by association: $ $ if $\,\bar p\sim p\,$ then $\,\bar p\mid a\color{red}\iff  p\mid a,\,$ therefore any property that is defined purely by divisibility is also preserved, including primality, viz.

$$\begin{align} \bar p\mid ab \color{red}\iff &\,p\mid ab\\[.2em] 
\iff &\,p\mid a\,\ {\rm or}\,\ p\mid b,\ \ \text{by $\,p\,$ prime}\\[.2em]
\color{red}\iff &\,\bar p\mid a\,\ {\rm or}\,\ \bar p\mid b_{\phantom{|}}\\[.6em]
 \hline
 \text{thus $\ p\,$ prime}\, \Longrightarrow\,&\,\ \bar p\ {\rm prime}\end{align}\qquad$$

**Remark** $ $ When studying divisibility theory in domains it is often convenient to ignore units by  working modulo the unit group, i.e. we consider elements congruent if they are associate. The quotient monoid is known as the *reduced* monoid and it is the standard place to begin study of factorization in general domains (at least for those properties that are monoid-theoretic). See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3110724/242) for further discussion, literature references and examples, e.g. characterizations of UFDs and gcd-domains in terms of their divisibility groups.