# Canonical unit multiples in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

I'm writing code to do computation in algebraic number fields and am (re)-learning some algebra in the process.

When working with a ring, it seems useful to have an operation that "canonicalizes" a nonzero element with respect to multiplication by [units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)). For example, in $\Bbb Z$, whose units are $\pm1$, we can take "canonical = positive". In the [polynomial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring) $K[X]$ where $K$ is a field, we can take "canonical = monic". This lets us (for example) produce unique representations for elements of a [field of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions) by ensuring the denominators are canonical.

This got me wondering about other rings. In particular, in [$\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n), is there a "natural" and/or efficient-to-compute canonicalization operation? Of course, we could just take the canonical unit multiple of a given element to be the smallest positive one (which will always be $\le n/2$ since $x\mapsto n-x$ is equivalent to multiplication by $-1$), but is there something "nicer" (maybe something that works in any quotient ring)? I realize this is an imprecise question; any insight is appreciated.

Comment: This is sometimes called [unit normalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2939562/242).

Comment: Modding out the multiplicative monoid by the unit group yields the [divisibility monoids & groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3110724/242). Follow the link for some protypical results. Essentially you seek normal forms in these structures, which is difficult in general.