# How do you prove $\sqrt{n}$ is an integer or it is irrational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

I have tried this problem five times but I keep getting stuck. I keep following the proof for $\sqrt{2}$. I know that I have to prove that the set is nonempty. Which I do by induction.

$2^1 > 1$

assume $2^n > n$ and prove $2^{n+1} > n+1$

$2^n + 2^n > n+n > n$

Then I think I have to prove that it has an upper bound. Also, I think it has something to do with prime numbers?

Comment: Like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show that if $n^{1/2}$ is a rational number, then $n^{1/2}$ is an integer.

Suppose that $n^{1/2}=\frac{a}{b}$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers. We may without loss of generality assume that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, and that $b\ge 1$. We show that $b=1$.

Suppose to the contrary that $b\gt 1$. Then some prime $p$ divides $b$.

From $n^{1/2}=\frac{a}{b}$, we get that $b^2n=a^2$. Since $p$ divides $b$, we conclude that $p$ must divide $a^2$, so $p$ divides $a$. This contradicts the fact that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

So $n^{1/2}=\frac{a}{1}$, and therefore $n^{1/2}$ is an integer.

Comment: It is worth emphasis that, although not explicitly mentioned, the proof depends *crucially* on the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, i.e. the existence *and* uniqueness of prime factorizations. The statement generally fails in domains lacking this property.

Comment: The proof depends strongly on "Euclid's Lemma," in this instance the fact that if a prime divides $xy$, then $p$ divides $x$ or $p$ divides $y$. I agree that after the Lemma, the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is straightforward, but the proof above only uses the Lemma.

Comment: Euclid's Lemma is *equivalent* to the *uniqueness* of prime factorizations (as are many closely related properties, e.g. [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/164589/242) for over 15 more equivalents)