# The largest algebraic structure in which every irreducible is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

We know that in a UFD every irreducible is prime.

But [this document](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/m4363s07/non_ufd.pdf) rise up in my mind a question that; is there a known algebraic structure (larger than a UFD) in which every irreducible is prime?
Is there a name for such integral domains?

Thanks for sharing any knowledge,

Comment: Sure, gcd domains and various generalizations thereof, e.g. domains satisfying variants of Euclid's Lemma or Gauss's Lemma, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/164589/242) for a handful. They are sometimes called AP domains (Atoms are Prime)$\ $

Comment: Yes, I have heard of GCD domains before, some of the others are new to me. Thanks, But I would love to read your post you have referred there, which I am not able to open from the Google-groups link given there- most probably because of my browser? Could you please send that post as an answer here with a note maybe where this kind of domains fall exactly into, if you don't mind?

Answer (score 1):

A domain is called atomic if each non-zero and  non-invertible elements is a product of irreducible elements.

It can be shown that for an *atomic* domain $D$ it is equivalent:

- $D$ is a UFD.
- Each irreducible in $D$ is prime.

That is for atomic domains there is nothing but UFDs. 
On the other hand a UFD is always atomic; as a prime is always irreducible.

Thus, if one wants to have something beyond UFDs one needs to leave the realm of domains where each element has a factorization into irreducibles.  As Bill Dubuque mentions this is well possible and done. The "largest," that is most inclusive, defintion you seek would be just: "a domain where each irreducible is prime." A name for this is AP-domain (see comment by OP).

In such a domain it is true that every non-zero non-identity element has *at most* one factorization into irreducibles (up to multiplication by units and reordering).

Note that for a UFD one has the characterization  each non-zero non-identity element has *exactly* one factorization into irreducibles (up to multiplication by units and reordering)

Put differently, in an AP-domain it is true that each element that *has* a factorization into irreducibles at all has a (essentially) unique factorization.

Such a domain is called an unrestricted UFD by Coykendall and Zafrullah. Thus, every AP-domain is an unrestricted UFD. The converse is not true though as shown by Coykendall and Zafrullah (in contrast to the situation for atomic domains).

A relevant paper is: Jim Coykendall, Muhammad Zafrullah, [AP-domains and unique factorization](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2003.10.036), Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra (2004).

Comment: I am not sure that atomic domains should have irreducibles as primes...?

Comment: I have just found this paper from 1991 https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~coykenda/paper30b.pdf in which it refers to these domains as AP-domains but it does not seem to fully characterize them. But it differs the atomic property from AP condition (irreducibles being prime)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with your first comment. The paper you mention is very relavant; I was not aware of this. In fact I made an error. I will update the answer.

Comment: S.B. is right. An atomic domain in which every atom is a prime is a UFD, and this has been pointed out in the Coykendall-Zafrullah paper, but there are atomic domains in which some atoms are not prime. If some readers need to they may consult: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/249044621_Examples_in_modern_algebra_with_which_students_can_play

Answer (score 0):

It so happens that I addressed this question in hd1203, in the year 2012. Those looking for a characterization for domains in which atoms are prime may want to look up: http://www.lohar.com/mithelpdesk/hd1203.pdf

In the above write up, that ended in 2012, you will find descriptions of domains in which atoms are usually prime, domains such as pre-Schreier domains, PSP domains etc.