# Integral domain with two elements that do not have a gcd

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

I have the following example of an integral domain with two elements that do not have a gcd from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#The_gcd_in_commutative_rings):

$R = \mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-3}\,\,\right],\quad a = 4 = 2\cdot 2 = \left(1+\sqrt{-3}\,\,\right)\left(1-\sqrt{-3}\,\,\right),\quad b = \left(1+\sqrt{-3}\,\,\right)\cdot 2.$

The elements $2$ and $1 + \sqrt{−3}$ are two "maximal common divisors" (i.e. any common divisor which is a multiple of $2$ is associated to $2$, the same holds for $1 + \sqrt{−3}$), but they are not associated, so there is no greatest common divisor of a and b.

I can understand it, but how can I prove or strictly explain that $2$ and $1 + \sqrt{−3}$ are two "maximal common divisors" and they are not associated?

Comment: What can the norm of a common divisor be? What elements have those norms?

Comment: @Yuan I found the concept of multiplicative norms, defined by $N(a+b\sqrt{-3})=a^2+3b^2$ in here. Do you mean this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A simple but general way to deduce that this gcd fails to exist is by failure of Euclid's Lemma.

**Lemma** $\rm\ \ (a,b) = (ac,bc)/c\ \ $  if $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists $\rm\quad$ [[GCD distributive law]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242)

**Proof** $\rm\quad d\ |\ a,b\iff dc\ |\ ac,bc\iff dc\ |\ (ac,bc)\iff d\mid (ac,bc)/c$

But generally $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ need not exist, as is most insightfully viewed as failure of

**Euclid's Lemma**  $\rm\quad a\ |\ bc\ $ and $\rm\ (a,b)=1\ \Rightarrow\ a\ |\ c\ \ $ if $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists.

**Proof** $\ \ $ If $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists then $\rm\ a\ |\ ac,bc\ \Rightarrow\ a\ |\ (ac,bc) = (a,b)\,c = c\ $  by the Lemma.

Hence if $\rm\, a,b,c\, $ fail to satisfy the Euclid Lemma $\Rightarrow,\,$
namely  if  $\rm\ a\ |\ bc\ $  and  $\rm\ (a,b) = 1\ $  but $\rm\ a\nmid c\,$, then one immediately deduces that the gcd $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ fails to exist.$\,$  For the special case that $\rm\,a\,$ is an atom (i.e. irreducible), the implication reduces to: atom $\Rightarrow$ prime. So it suffices to find a nonprime atom
in order to exhibit a pair of elements whose gcd fails to exist. This task is a bit simpler, e.g. for $\rm\ \omega = 1 + \sqrt{-3}\ \in\ \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]\ $ we have that the atom $\rm\, 2\ |\ \omega' \omega = 4,\,$ but $\rm\ 2\nmid \omega',\omega,\,$ so $\rm\,2\,$ is not prime. Therefore your gcd $\rm\, (2\omega,\, \omega'\omega) = (2+2\sqrt{-3},\,4)\ $ fails to exist in $\rm\ \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]\,$.

Note that if the gcd $\rm\, (ac,bc)\ $ fails to exist then this implies that the ideal $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ is not principal. Therefore we've *constructively*  deduced that the failure of Euclid's lemma immediately yields both a nonexistent gcd and a nonprincipal ideal.

That the $\Rightarrow$ in Euclid's lemma implies that Atoms are Prime $\rm(:= AP)$ is denoted $\rm\ D\ \Rightarrow AP\ $ in the list of domains closely related to GCD domains in my [post here.](http://groups.google.com/groups?selm=y8z8yto8k85.fsf@nestle.ai.mit.edu) There you will find links to further literature on domains closely related to GCD domains. See especially the referenced comprehensive survey by D.D. Anderson: *GCD domains, Gauss' lemma, and contents of polynomials*, 2000.

See also my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m/3149#3149) for the general *universal* definitions of $\rm GCD,\, LCM$ and for further remarks on how such $\iff$ definitions enable slick proofs, and [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-emptyset/3832#3832) for another simple example of such.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I understood this and knew some other interesting concepts. Later I want to study them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the concept ''maximal common divisors''.
But I prove it directly.

Suppose that $d=\gcd{(4, 2(1+\sqrt{-3})}$ exists.
Since $4=2\cdot 2=(1+\sqrt{-3})(1-\sqrt{-3})$,
we get that $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-3}$ both are common divisor of $4$ and $2(1+\sqrt{-3})$.
Thus, $2\mid d$ and $(1+\sqrt{-3})\mid d$.

Note that $2\mid d$ and $d\mid 4$ follows that $d\in\{\pm 2\}$.
These $d$ can't satisfy $(1+\sqrt{-3})\mid d$.