# Modular arithmetic: division, fractions, solving linear congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to ask a question about modular arithmetic. I know, that modular multiplicative inverse exists only if modulo and integer are relatively prime. I want to know, are there any ways of division in modular arithmetic, if modulo and integer aren't relatively prime? I tried to find info about that, but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below I explain how to view modular division via (possibly *multiple-valued*) modular fractions.

Consider $\,x\equiv A/B\pmod{\!M},\,$ i.e. the *solution**s*** of $\ B\, x \equiv A\pmod{\!M}.\, $ Let $\,d=\gcd(B,M).\,$  Then $\, d\mid B,\,\ d\mid M\mid B\,x\!-\!A\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid A\ $ is a *neccessary* condition for *existence* of solutions.

If so, let $\  m, a, b \, =\, M/d,\, A/d,\, B/d.\ $ Then cancelling $\,d\,$ throughout yields

$$ x\equiv \dfrac{A}B\!\!\!\pmod{\!M}\iff  M\mid B\,x\!-\!A\!\! \overset{\large {\ \ \color{#c00}{{\rm cancel}\ d}}}\iff  m\mid b\,x\! -\! a \iff x\equiv \dfrac{a}b\!\!\!\pmod{\!m}$$

where the fraction $\  x\equiv a/b\pmod{\! m}\,$ denotes *all* solutions of $\,ax\equiv b\pmod{\! m},\, $ and similarly for $\, $ the $\, $ fraction $\ x\equiv A/B\pmod{\!M}.\ $

The above argument implies that if solutions exist then we can compute the complete solution set  by $\color{#c00}{{\rm cancelling}\ d} = (B,M)\,$ from the numerator $\,A,\,$ the denominator $\,B\,$ $\rm\color{#c00}{and}$ the modulus $\,M,\,$ i.e.

$$ \bbox[8px,border:1px solid #c00]{x\equiv \dfrac{a\color{#c00}d}{b\color{#c00}d}\!\!\!\pmod{\!m\color{#c00}d}\iff x\equiv \dfrac{a}b\!\!\!\pmod{\! m}}\qquad$$

If $\, d>1\, $ then $\, x\equiv A/B\pmod{\!M}\,$ is *multiple-valued,* having $\,d\,$ solutions in AP, namely

$$\quad\ \begin{align} x \equiv a/b\!\!\pmod{\! m}\,  &\equiv\, \{\, a/b + k\,m\}_{\,\large  0\le k<d}\!\!\pmod{\!M},\ \ M = md\\ 
&\equiv\, \{a/b,\,\ a/b\! +\! m,\,\ldots,\, a/b\! +\! (d\!-\!1)m\}\!\!\pmod{\! M}
\end{align}$$

which is true because $\ km\bmod dm =\, (\color{#c00}{k\bmod d})\, m\ $ by the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), $ $ and the RHS  takes *exactly* $\,d\,$ values, namely $\,\color{#c00}0m,\, \color{#c00}1m,\, \color{#c00}2m, \ldots, (\color{#c00}{d\!-\!1})m,\, $ so ditto for their shifts by $\,a/b$.

$ {\rm e.g.} \overbrace{\dfrac{6}3\pmod{\!12}}^{{\rm\large cancel}\ \ \Large (3,12)\,=\,\color{#c00}3}\!\!\!\!\equiv \dfrac{2}{1}\!\pmod{\!4}\equiv \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\overbrace{\{2,6,10\}}^{\qquad\ \ \,\Large\{ 2\ +\ 4k\}_{\ \Large 0\le k< 3}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!12},\ $ indeed $\ 3\{2,6,10\}\equiv \{6\}$

Note in particular that a modular "fraction"  may denote zero, one, or multiple solutions.

---

**Remark** $ $ A nice application of modular fractions is the *fractional* extended Euclidean algorithm described in the [Remark here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) There you'll find explicit examples of the intersection of solution sets of multiple-valued modular fractions.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for motivation.

Answer (score 2):

You can cancel a factor common to both sides of a congruence AND the modulus. The justification for this is that for any non-zero integer $d$ we have $dm\mid (da-db)$ if and only if $m\mid (a-b)$. Written as congruences this reads
$$da\equiv db\pmod{dm}\Longleftrightarrow a\equiv b\pmod m.$$

So for example the congruence $$6x\equiv 8\pmod {10}$$ is equivalent to the the congruence $$3x\equiv4\pmod5.$$ This time you ended with a linear congruence where the coprimeness condition $\gcd(3,5)=1$ holds, and you can proceed to solve this congruence with the usual methods.

Observe also that it is often easy to show that a linear congruence has no solutions when to gcd-condition fails. Consider
$$6x\equiv 7\pmod{10}.$$
Here $6x$ is always even, as is $10$, but $7$ is not. Therefore this congruence cannot have any solutions in $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: This is surely a dupe, but I didn't find a good target. Turning to CW.