# $12x \equiv 33 \pmod{57}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can you show me a step by step instruction how to solve this problem?

$$12x \equiv 33 \pmod{57}$$

Comment: Solve it mod 3 and mod 19

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
12x &\equiv& 33 & \pmod {57} \\
4x &\equiv& 11 & \pmod {19} \\
4x &\equiv& -8 & \pmod {19} \\
\end{array}$$

You can reduce them by $4$ as $4$ is relatively prime wiht $19$

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
4x &\equiv& -8 & \pmod {19} \\
x &\equiv& -2 & \pmod {19} \\
x &\equiv& 17 & \pmod {19} \\
\end{array}$$

$$x=19n+17$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
12x &\equiv& 33 & \pmod {57} \\
4x &\equiv& 11 & \pmod {19} \\
(4x)(5) &\equiv& (11)(5) & \pmod {19} \\
20x &\equiv& 17 & \pmod {19} \\
x &\equiv& 17 & \pmod {19} \\
x &\equiv& 17,36,55 & \pmod {57} \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Note first that it is equivalent to 
$$4x\equiv 11\pmod{19},$$
and to solve this equation, all you have to do is finding the inverse of $4\bmod 19$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ As $ $ [explained here:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2410059/242) $\quad \begin{align} & \bmod 19(\color{#c00}{3})\!:\,\ x\equiv \dfrac{11}{4}\color{#c00}{\dfrac{3}{3}}\\[.3em]
\overset{\large\ \ \div\,  \color{#c00}3}\iff\, &\bmod  19\!:\quad\ \ \ x\equiv \dfrac{11}{4}\equiv\dfrac{-8}{4}\equiv -2\equiv 17\end{align} $