# Name of Modulus Theorems

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let *p* and *q* be two positive integers with *r* being their greatest common factor. Consider the set *E* such that

$E = \{0,\:\:r, \:\:2r,\:\:3r,\:\: ...,\:\: (q-r)\}$

Let *a<sub>n</sub>* be a sequence defined for integers *n* within the interval *[0, q-1]* such that

$a_n = (np) \bmod q$

For every integer, *k*, within set, *E*, there is a corresponding *n(k)* such that

$a_{n(k)} = k$

I am able to prove this theorem from scratch, but I would like to know if there are any existing theorems within Discrete Mathematics (or another branch of math) that is able to help prove this theorem quicker.  Do such theorems exists?  And if so, I would also like to ask if there is a resource that presents a large number of them.

Comment: If my answer isn't clear let me know what you'd like elaborated.

Answer (score 0):

If we unwind your definitions then your claim is equivalent to  the following very well-known result about the solution of a general linear congruence, replacing your $\,n\,$ by $\,x,\,$ and where $\frac{a}b := ab^{-1}$

$${\rm if}\ \ \ r := (p,q)\mid k\ \ \ {\rm then}\ \ \    p\,x \equiv k\!\!\!\pmod{\!q}\!\iff\! x\equiv \dfrac{k/r}{p/r}\!\!\!\pmod{\!q/r}\qquad\qquad$$

You can find a proof of this and further discussion [this answer,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2410059/242) and in most number theory textbooks.

**Remark** $ $  The congruence has a solution $\,x\in\Bbb Z\iff r\mid k.\,$ Above shows $(\Leftarrow)$. For the converse $(\Rightarrow)\ $ if $\,x_0\,$ is a solution then for some $\,j\!:\, $ $\, p\,x_0+q\,j = k\,$ so $\,r\mid p,q\,\Rightarrow\, r\mid p\,x_0+q\,j = k.\,$ Or, by congruences  $\,\bmod r\!:\,\ k\equiv px\equiv 0\,$ by $\,p\equiv 0\ $ (the [congruence persists](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883060/242) $\!\bmod r\,$ by $\,r\mid q)$