# How to find all possible integers for a given congruence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I was given a statement:

$$kx^3 \equiv n \pmod m = 3 \pmod 9$$

## Trying to solve it

A user gave me some tips in the comment section under this question. Trying to use it to solve my problem:

$$kx^3 \equiv 3 \pmod 9 \Longleftrightarrow d = gcd(x,9) | 3$$
$$k \equiv \frac{n}{x^3}  \mod \frac{m}{d} = \frac{3}{x^3} \mod \frac{9}{3}$$

So the solution is that x has to be 1 or else there will never come a whole integer out. Solving this for $x=1$:
$$k = 0.$$

**Is that correct?**

Comment: Do you know how to solve $\ b x \equiv n\pmod{m}?\  $ Above is a special case $\,b = c^3\ \ \ $

Comment: Sadly, I do not know how to solve it. I am totally lost.

Comment: What is your context? Normally one would not be posed such exercises before one  learned the basic techniques of solving linear congruences. Do you know about modular inverses?

Comment: @BillDubuque well, I know about the Euclidian Algorithm. And yes, I know about modular inverses.

Comment: There are many prior answers here explaining how to solve a general linear congruence, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242). Your congruence is a special case (when the lead coef is a cube).

Comment: @BillDubuque thank you, I have tried it to some extent. But I am very unsure of what I have done is right. I have edited the post to fit that into the question.

Comment: By [general theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2410059/242) $\,a\, k \equiv n\pmod{\!m}\,$ is solvable $\iff  d=\gcd(a,m)\mid n.\,$ If so then the solution is $\,  k \equiv (n/d)/(a/d) \pmod{\!m/d}.\ $ Yours is special case $\,a = c^3\ \ \ $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106309/discussion-between-heinrich-jensen-and-bill-dubuque).