# For some arbitrary natural numbers $n,i$ with $n<k,i \leq k+1$, does there always exists some natural $x \leq k-1$ such that $k \mid n+xi$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For  some arbitrary natural numbers $n,i$ with $n<k,i \leq k+1$, does there always exists  some natural $x \leq k-1$ such that $k \mid n+xi$?

---

So we want $ xi \equiv -n \pmod k$. Reduced residue class of $k$ consist ${0,1,2,...,k-1}$, that is $k$ elements, so with all the bounds given in the problem, I was thinking of getting some PHP argument, but I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that there are $k-1$ elements that you listed out. Maybe you forgot to include 0?

Comment: Hint: No. $\quad$ Now go find a counter example. How can we ensure that $k \not \mid n+xi$?

Comment: @CalvinLin oh yeah you're right, i did forget to include 0.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2410059/242) in the linked dupe for necessary (and sufficient) conditions for solvability of a linear congruence.