# Is my simplification of the problem "How many solutions does the equation $6x = 5$ have in $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$" correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve the following problem:

How many solutions does the equation $6x = 5$ have in $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$

The equivalent of asking:

How many solutions does the equation $6x = 5$ have in $\mathbb{F}9$?

From my understanding $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ is simply the set of possible values of integers mod $9$, so it is the set $[0, 9)$ which is equivalent to $\mathbb{F}9$. I just wanted to check that my understanding is correct.

Comment: If by $\mathbb{F}_9$ you mean the field with nine elements, then *no*. $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to the field with nine elements: it's not a field at all. For example, $\overline{3}\neq \overline{0}$, but $\overline{3}\times\overline{3}=\overline{0}$. It's a common beginner's error.

Comment: Your understanding is not correct.  Every element of the field $\Bbb F_9$ satisfies $3x=0$.  That’s not true of $\Bbb Z/9 \Bbb Z,$ which is not a field.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Do you mind providing an example (links, videos, etc.) on how to solve equations in quotient groups?

Comment: This is a modular problem, an elementary number theory problem, very little if anything to do with group theory or quotient groups. You are trying to solve the congruence $6x\equiv 5\pmod{9}$. [The standard methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195871/existence-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-linear-congruences-cx-equiv-b-pmod-m) for solving this congruence are all you need.

Comment: Your tags were woefully incorrect. What the heck does this have to do with Galois Theory?!

Comment: In a field there is one solution to the equation because each non-zero element of the field has a unique multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all ,[0,9) represents interval which means it contains all real numbers x such that 0≤x<9.

So, you cannot write it in this way.

More over, Z/9Z is not isomorphic to F9.
Z/9Z has zero divisior.(3×3 is equivalent to 0 in Z9) .
Remember ,
Zn is field iff n is prime.
so, Z9 cannot be a field.

Comment: Please use Mathjax.