# Congruences, elementary number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\gcd(c,m)=1$ and if $ca≡cb \pmod m$ for some $a$ and $b$, one may argue that $a≡b \pmod m$.  Note that this claim says that there are situations where we can "cancel" $c\mod m$.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1):

As $\operatorname{gcd}(c,m) = 1$, we have $\alpha c + \beta m = 1$ for some integers $\alpha, \beta$. Now $(a-b)c = km$ for some integer $k$. Multiplying by $\alpha$ gives $(a-b)\alpha c = \alpha km$, hence
\[ (a-b)(1 - \beta m) = \alpha km \iff (a-b) = \bigl((\alpha k + (a-b)\beta\bigr)m \]
So $a \equiv b \pmod m$.

Comment: I don't see how you get that last line.  $(a-b)=(\alpha k+ \beta)m$

Comment: @user42783 Thx, corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Put $\rm\:d = a\!-\!b\ $  in: $\ $ if $\rm\ gcd(m,c)=1\:$ then $\rm\: m\:|\:c\,d\:\Rightarrow\: m\:|\:d\ $ [(Euclid's Lemma)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37089/242)

Alternatively, congruentially, an element $\rm\:c\:$ coprime to the modulus is a unit (invertible) mod $\rm\,m\,$ by [Bezout's identity,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezout's_identity) so it can be cancelled from equations (congruences), i.e.

$$\rm (c,m)=1\ \Rightarrow\ c^{-1}\  exists,\ thus\ \ c^{-1}\  times\ \ ca\equiv cb\ \ yields \ \ a\equiv b$$

Generally, in *any* ring,  scaling an equation by a unit yields an equivalent equation, because, as above, invertible elements are cancellable.