# If $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ are relatively prime and $a < b$, then $ka$ can't be a multiple of $b$ for $k < a$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The statement in the title seems obviously true to me, but I can't quite prove it.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ By [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37089/242) $\rm\ (b,a)=1,\,\ b\:|\:ak\:\Rightarrow\:b\:|\:k\:\Rightarrow\: b \le k < a$

Answer (score 1):

If $ka$ is a multiple of $b, ka=bc$ for some integer $c$.

$\implies c=\frac{ka}{b} \implies b\mid k$ as $(a,b)=1$

But as $a<b$ and $k<a\implies k<b, b$ can not divide $k$.

Comment: I also just realized that my statement follows from the fact lcm(a, b) = ab.

Comment: @DDD, ya, so $k$ can not be $<b$.