# Example of a non-gcd domain

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, integral-domain

An integral domain $R $ is a gcd-domain if for all $a,b \in R\setminus \{0\} $ there exists $d\in R  $ such that

- $d$ divides both $a $ and $b $
- for all $d'$ in $R $, if $d'  $ is a common divisor of $a $ and $b $ then $d'  $ divides $d $

But I can't come up with an example of integral domain which is not a gcd-domain. Can you find one or give me a hint ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37089/242) for some insight on the standard quadratic integer examples.

Comment: $ x^5 $ and $ x^6 $ have no gcd in, for instance, the integral domain $ \{ $ real polynomials without $ x $ term $ \} $.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All subdomains of $\mathbb{C}$ are integral domains. However, not all subdomains of $\mathbb{C}$ are [unique factorization domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain).

An example of such a ring is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.
In this ring, $6 = 2 \cdot 3$ but also $6 = (1 + \sqrt{-5}) \cdot (1 - \sqrt{-5}) $.
By looking at the norms of $2, 3, (1 + \sqrt{-5})$ and $(1 - \sqrt{-5})$ and using $\lvert ab \rvert = \lvert a \rvert \cdot \lvert b \rvert$, you can see that each of those elements is an irreducible element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. Therefore, they cannot divide each other.

Now look at $\gcd(6, 2 + 2\sqrt{-5})$.
Those numbers have $2$ and $(1 + \sqrt{-5})$ as common divisors, but those don't divide each other.

Comment: I see why that ring is not a UFD but I don't understand which elements $a $ and $b $ to choose to get a counterexample to the the property

Comment: Yes, i just notices that this might not lead to what you are looking for. I'll think about it a bit.

Comment: *G.C.D. domains* are not necessarily *U.F.D.s*.

Comment: I think that should work now.

Comment: What about $Z/4Z$ which is not an UFD ??