# Quick question about the $gcd$ in ring theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2163483/382204) answer from a previous post. Particularly the last line. Why $2\mid d$ and $d\mid 4$ follows that $d\in\{\pm 1, \pm 2\}$? I think it should be  $d\in\{\pm 1, \pm 2 \pm 4\}$ and therefore if $d=4$, $d$ could satisfy $(1+\sqrt{-3})\mid d$

Comment: Why not post a comment directly to that answer so the author can reply?

Comment: Well, you’re talking about natural integers ($\Bbb Z$) only. So no radicals. But $2$ does not divide $d=\pm1$.

Comment: @Lubin then $d$ should only be $\pm 2$? Why not $\pm 4$, since $2|4$ and $4|4$?

Comment: I didn’t say that at all. Of course $\pm2$ and $\pm4$ are the possibilities.

Comment: Then that answer is wrong, right? Since if  $d\in\{\pm 2 \pm 4\}$ ,$d$ could satisfy $(1+\sqrt{-3})\mid d$ for $d=4$.