# Let $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, Show that $ab\mid c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ such that greatest common divisor (gcd) $\gcd(a,b)=1$, Show that $ab\mid c$.

Comment: Hint: Write a,b,c in their prime factorizations and use the given information.

Comment: what is "prime factorization " do you mean a|c ~ c=aq?

Comment: The factorization theorem for the integers says that every integer can be uniquely written as a product of primes.

Comment: I ask more hints to solve the problem.

Comment: @Alvou: Please don't post in a commanding tone (Show that...), please accept satisfactory answers to your questions (this one and previous ones). What have you tried?

Comment: To all who repeatedly suggest using prime factorizations: this is frequently used towards the proof of the FTA. So it would be best if that were not used. In particular, there are proofs that do not use FTA. (I know Rosen's book develops this before FTA, for example).

Comment: Some related posts:
[Show that if $a | c$ and $b | c$, then $ab | c$ when $a$ is coprime to $b$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/173471),
[Prove: If $a|m$ and $b|m$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $ab|m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/194961), 
[If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a$ and $b$ divide $c$, then so does $ab$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/407540).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\quad\ \ a,b\ |\ c\ \Rightarrow\ ab\ |\ ac,bc\ \Rightarrow\ ab\ |\ (ac,bc) = (a,b)c =  c\ $ via $\rm\:(a,b)= 1\:.$

**Note** $\ $  This proof works in *every* domain where GCDs exist, since it doesn't use Bezout's identity. Instead it uses the [GCD distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242) $\rm\ (ac,bc) = (a,b)c\:,\ $ true in every GCD domain, viz.

**Lemma** $\rm\quad (a,b)\ =\ (ac,bc)/c\ \ $ if $\rm\ (ac,bc)\ $ exists.

**Proof** $\rm\quad\ d\ |\ a,b\ \iff\ dc\ |\ ac,bc\ \iff\ dc\ |\ (ac,bc)\ \iff\ d\ |\ (ac,bc)/c$

The above proofs use the [*universal* definitions of GCD, LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m/3149#3149), which often serve to simplify proofs, e.g. see [this proof of the GCD * LCM law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-emptyset/3832#3832)

Answer (score 4):

If $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)=1$ then there exist $x,y$ such that $ax+by=1$.  Now let $a,b|c$ and note that $c = cax+cby$.  Can you show that both terms on the right hand side are divisible by $ab$?

Comment: why do you divide both terms on the right hand by ab?

Comment: @alvoutila, because you want to show that $ab | c$?

Comment: thanks that helped. So if a|c ~ c=aq and b|c ~ c=bq' then if syt(a,b)=xa+yb=1 => c=xca+ybc = x bq'a+yaqb=ab(xq'+yq)=abq'' => ab|c. Isn't it

Comment: First sentence is [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity).

Comment: @alvoutila, you are right. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using set theory.

Let the set $A$ be the prime factors of $a$,

set $B$ be the set of prime factors of $b$,

and set $C$ be the prime factors of $c$.

- $a\;|\;c\Longrightarrow A\subset C$
- $b\;|\;c\Longrightarrow B\subset C$
- $\gcd(a,b) = 1 \Longrightarrow A\cap B\subset \varnothing$

We want to show that $ab\;|\;c  \Longrightarrow A \cup B \subseteq C$.

Do you see why this is given the $3$ points above?