# Proving ${\rm gcd}(a,b)=1$, $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ implies $ab\mid c$ WITHOUT Euclid's or Bezout's lemma.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

I want to show prove the following statement:
For any $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$, if $a,b$ are coprime and both $a$ and $b$ divide $c$, then $ab$ has to divide $c$ as well.

Before marking this as a duplicate - I've spent some time searching and I couldn't find an elementary proof that does not rely on Euclid's or Bezout's lemma.

My approach is as follows:

Since $b$ divides $c$, there exists an integer $k$, such that $kb=c$.

Since $a$ divides $c$, by identity it also divides $kb$.

I now want to show that assuming $a$ doesn't divide $kb$ implies the existence of a common divisor $d>1$ of $a$ and $b$, however, I'm walking in circles trying to prove this step.

I'm not 100% sure there's an easy way to prove it, but I'd appreciate any hint on how to prove the statement *without* using Euclid's or Bezout's lemma, just using the definition of divisibility

$x\mid y\ \Rightarrow\ \exists\ z\in\mathbb Z:zx=y$

and Euclidean division

$\forall\ x\in\mathbb Z,y\in\mathbb Z^\times\ \exists\ q\in\mathbb Z,r\in\{0,\ldots,y-1\}:x=qy+r$.

Comment: It is a consequence of gauss lemma

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**  $\,d\mapsto ab/d\,$ bijects the common divisors $\,d\,$ of $\,a,b\,$ with the common multiples $\le ab.$ Being order-$\rm\color{#c00}{reversing}$, it maps the $\rm\color{#c00}{Greatest}$ common divisor to the $\rm\color{#c00}{Least}$ common multiple, i.e. $\,{\rm\color{#c00}{G}CD}(a,b)\mapsto ab/{\rm GCD}(a,b) = {\rm \color{#c00}{L }CM}(a,b).\,$

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_p(x)$ be the exponent of a prime $p$ in the decomposition of $x$.

- $x \mid y$ iff $v_p(x) \le v_p(y)$ for all $p$.
- $\gcd(a,b)=1$ implies $v_p(ab) = v_p(a)$ or $v_b(p)$.
- $a \mid c $ implies $v_p(a) \le v_p(c)$
- $b \mid c $ implies $v_p(b) \le v_p(c)$

The result follows.