# Suppose that $a, m$ and $n$ are positive integers such that $(m, n)=1$. If $m\mid a$ and $n\mid a$, then $mn\mid a$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm

prove or disprove :

Suppose that $a$, $m$ and $n$ are positive integers such that $(m, n)=1$. If $m\mid a$ and $n\mid a$, then $mn\mid a$.
 I think it is true statement.

Let $m\mid a$ and $n\mid a$ then $mn\mid na$ and $nm\mid ma$ since $(m,n)=1$ then $mn\mid a$.

Ut is short answer and I am not sure if that is it complete answer?

Comment: I wouldn't mark it correct unless you gave a more precise reason (than $(m,n)=1$) why  $mn|a$ .

Comment: If $(m,n)=1$, then $(ma,na)=a$. if  $mn\mid na$ and $mn\mid ma$, then $mn\mid a$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I see my mistake ,the correct that if m|na and since (m,n)=1 then m|a but which I did I think there is mistake any help with that please.

Comment: I think it is best to finish it off the way @José Carlos Santos does in his solution.

Comment: @ancientmathematician thank you so much

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173471/show-that-if-a-c-and-b-c-then-ab-c-when-a-is-coprime-to-b
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194961/prove-if-am-and-bm-and-gcda-b-1-then-abm
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407540/if-gcda-b-1-and-a-and-b-divide-c-then-so-does-ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You prove correctly that $mn$ divides both $ma$ and $na$. Since $(m,n)=1$, there are $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $xm+yn=1$ and therefore $xma+yna=a$. Since $mn$ divides both $ma$ and $na$, it follows from this that $mn\mid a$.