# Explaining the definition about greatest common divisor, what do they mean up to the equivalence relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The definition of gcd is provided below:

Let R be an principal ideal domain. Let a,b ∈ R. Then there is a greatest
common divisor of a and b, that is, an element d that divides both a and
b and such that if c divides both a and b, then c divides d. The element d is
unique up to the equivalence relation ∼ (a ∼ b if a and b are associate).

Here, a ~ b means a|b and b|a which was proved to be an equivalence relation.

My question is what do they mean by "up to the equivalence relation ~"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess that $a \sim b$ if and only if there exists a unit $u \in R$ such that $a = u b$.

Comment: yes, sorry, you are right, what you said is the definiton. what I said was the prop

Answer (score 2):

When you have an equivalence relation you separate the set into equivalence classes.  Just as $d$ divides $a$ and $b$, so does any associate of $d$.  Any of the associates of $d$ would work as well.  As an example, in the Gaussian integers, the units are $1,-1,i,-i$ and the associates of a number are the number multiplied by these.  Once you know, for example, that the GCD of $8$ and $3+3i$ is $1+i$, you know that $-1-i, -1+i, 1-i$ are also GCDs and that is all there are.  All the elements of the equivalence class are GCDs.

Answer (score 2):

This just means that if $d_1$ is a GCD of $a$ and $b$, and $d_2$ is also a GCD of $a$ and $b$, then $d_1 \sim d_2$.

Answer (score 0):

It means that $\,d\,$ and $\,d'$ are gcds $\,\iff d \sim d'.$ The idea is that *any* generator of the principal ideal generated by $\,a,b\,$ serves as a gcd, and such generators are unique only up to associates. The translation into ideal language is by the following chain of equivalence statements, using universal properties and "contains = divides" for principal ideals.

$$ (a,b) = (d)$$

$$(c) \supseteq (a,b) \iff (c) \supset (d)$$

$$ c\mid a,b \iff c\mid d$$

$$ d \sim \gcd( a,b)$$

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4129049/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1125068/242)

Answer (score -4):

It means that this statement is true as long as a and b are **not** equivalent.

Comment: No, if $a$ and $b$ are equivalent, the GCD is $a$ or $b$ (or one of the two associates that are left).