# Greatest Common Divisor is the least linear combination

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let d be the least positive linear combination of a and b.
It is not difficult to understand the proof that d is a common divisor of a and b.

> Since $d \ge 1$ and is a common divisor of a and b. d must be bigger than other common divisors.

Why d is the greatest? I'm not able to understand this statement. Any help is appreciated.

---

Follow up question:

> Any common divisor is a divisor of d

It makes sense if this is true, d is the gcd. But why is c|d instead of d|c?

Comment: Any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ divides any (integral) linear combination of them, in particular $d$.

Comment: Every common divisor also is a divisor of any $ax+by,$ hence a divisor of $d.$ So there can’t be any common divisor bigger than $d.$

Comment: I am not following here. why is any common divisor of a and b divides d?

Comment: Any common divisor of $a$, $b$ divides any linear combination of $a$, $b$

Comment: Recall [multiples are closed under $\rm\color{#0a0}{linear\ combinations}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2942475/242) therefore $\,c\mid a,b \Rightarrow c\mid \color{#0a0}{ja+kb}\! =\! \gcd(a,b),\,$ so $\,c\le \gcd(a,b),\,$ i.e. *linear* (Bezout) common divisors [are always greatest.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203450/242) In ideal language it boils down to the [universal property of the ideal sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1125068/242), i.e. $\,c\mid a,b\!\iff\! (c)\supseteq (a),(b) \!\iff\! (c)\supseteq (a)\!+\!(b)\! =\! (a,b)$

Comment: Good job with the duplicates @Bill. Underappreciated but necessary work for the site.