# Is $\gcd(\gcd(a,b),\gcd(c,d)) = \gcd(\gcd(a,c),\gcd(b,d))$ another instance of GCD Associativity?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, associativity

The question is as is in the title:

> Is $\gcd\bigg(\gcd(a,b),\gcd(c,d)\bigg) = \gcd\bigg(\gcd(a,c),\gcd(b,d)\bigg)$ another instance of GCD Associativity?

I know that
$$\gcd\bigg(e,\gcd(f,g)\bigg)=\gcd\bigg(\gcd(e,f),g\bigg)=\gcd(e,f,g).$$

I was wondering whether this can be extended to
$$\gcd\bigg(\gcd(a,b),\gcd(c,d)\bigg) = \gcd\bigg(\gcd(a,c),\gcd(b,d)\bigg) = \gcd\bigg(\gcd(a,d),\gcd(b,c)\bigg) = \gcd(a, b, c, d)?$$

I tried checking this [closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189424), but it appears that my inquiry is not covered there.

Comment: Those are all $\,\gcd(a,b,c,d)\,$, see for example [$\gcd(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n) = \gcd(\gcd(\gcd(a_1,a_2),a_3),\ldots.a_n)$ \[gcd is associative\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835180/gcda-1-a-2-ldots-a-n-gcd-gcd-gcda-1-a-2-a-3-ldots-a-n-gcd-is-as)

Comment: Just as I thought!  Thanks for confirming, @dxiv.  Please flesh out your last comment as an actual answer, so that I can upvote and then accept.  =)

Comment: This follows immediately by induction from the associativity (and commutativity) of the gcd (in the same way for any associative and commutative operation, e.g. ring addition or multiplication) - see the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those forms are equal, and equal to $\,\gcd(a,b,c,d)\,$. This follows from piecing together the results quoted below, whose full proofs can be found at the respective links.

- $\gcd(a,b)\,$ is commutative, by definition.
- $\gcd\,$ is associative, in the sense that $\,\gcd\left(\gcd(a,b),c\right)=\gcd\left(a, \gcd(b,c)\right)\,$, proved for example under [$\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)\,$ [Associative Law for GCD, LCM]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189424/gcda-b-c-gcd-gcda-b-c-associative-law-for-gcd-lcm).
- Associativity amounts to being able to "drop the parentheses", proved under [How does one actually show from associativity that one can drop parentheses?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21581/how-does-one-actually-show-from-associativity-that-one-can-drop-parentheses), and specifically for $\,\gcd\,$ under [$\gcd(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n) = \gcd(\gcd(\gcd(a_1,a_2),a_3),\ldots.a_n)$ [gcd is associative]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835180/gcda-1-a-2-ldots-a-n-gcd-gcd-gcda-1-a-2-a-3-ldots-a-n-gcd-is-as).

This means the multi-variate $\,\gcd(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)\,$ is well-defined and invariant to permutations of variables, so $\gcd\bigg(\gcd(a,b),\gcd(c,d)\bigg)$ $=\gcd(a,b,c,d)$  $= \gcd\bigg(\gcd(a,c),\gcd(b,d)\bigg)=\dots$

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ To emphasize the commutativity point in relation to ***this part*** of the question:

> ***Is*** $\gcd\bigg(\gcd(a,b),\gcd(c,d)\bigg) = \gcd\bigg(\gcd(a,c),\gcd(b,d)\bigg)$ ***another instance of GCD Associativity***?

The equality does hold true, indeed, but only because $\,\gcd\,$ is commutative in addition to being associative. If, for example, $\,a,b,c,d\,$ were square matrices of the same size, instead, and $\,\gcd\,$ were replaced with matrix multiplication, the equality $\,(a \cdot b) \cdot (c \cdot d) = (a \cdot c) \cdot (b \cdot d)\,$ would not hold true in general, because matrix multiplication *is* associative, but is *not* commutative.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque Technically, the question here also requires commutativity, not just associativity.

Comment: Of course, and I already [mentioned that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835180/gcda-1-a-2-ldots-a-n-gcd-gcd-gcda-1-a-2-a-3-ldots-a-n-gcd-is-as#comment9134816_1835180) but (mistakenly) on the dupe vs. here, Now propagated here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to define the $\gcd$ is to consider subgroups of $\mathbb Z$. Indeed such a subgroup is of the form $a\mathbb Z$ for some $a\ge0$.

Then the $\gcd$ of $a$ and $b$ is defined to be the unique positive integer satisfying
$$a\mathbb Z + b\mathbb Z = \gcd(a,b)\mathbb Z\,.$$

Since addition is associative and commutative, so is the $\gcd$. Specifically, your examples give

$$\begin{align}(a\mathbb Z + b\mathbb Z) + (c\mathbb Z + d\mathbb Z) 
&= (a\mathbb Z + c\mathbb Z)+(b\mathbb Z + d\mathbb Z) \\
&= (a\mathbb Z + d\mathbb Z)+(b\mathbb Z + c\mathbb Z) \\
&= a\mathbb Z + b\mathbb Z+c\mathbb Z + d\mathbb Z\,.\end{align}$$

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).