# If $d \mid a,b$ and $\exists x,y \in Z : d = ax + by$, then $d = \gcd(a,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

> If $d \mid a,b$ and $\exists x,y \in Z : d = ax + by$, then $d = \gcd(a,b)$

Well, I've tried by saying that $\gcd(a,b) \iff d = a s \cdot b  t$, and now $s=x,t=y$, and I've proved it.

I've also tried to find counter examples and failed. Although my proof seems to be odd, I'm looking forward to see what you can say about this. Thanks

Comment: This is called Bezout Theorem

Comment: [This proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198801/242) of the gcd universal property shows that linear common divisors are necessarily greatest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the statement "$d = \gcd(a,b)$", we should show (i) that $d$ divides $a$ and $b$, and (ii) that $d$ is the *greatest* such divisor, i.e. for any common divisor $k$ of $a$ and $b$, $k$ divides $d$.

Conveniently, (i) is given to us as a hypothesis.

For (ii), assume that $k$ divides $a$ and $b$. Now use the fact that $d = ax + by$. Can you conclude that $k$ divides $d$?

Comment: Well if I divide by $d$ the equation. I get $1 = a/dx + b/dy$, It means that $k < d$, which means $d$ is the greatest common divisor, what do you think?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS how did you conclude $k < d$ from that?

Comment: The gcd can't be lower than 1, so if we divide by $ k > d $ than we'll get $ p = ax + by $ and $ p < 1 $ which can't be true.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS I see, yes, that is correct.