# Prove $\,a\mid A,\, b\mid B\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid {\rm lcm}(A,B)$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, gcd-and-lcm

$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$Suppose $x\mid a$ and $y\mid b$ then can we say that $\lcm(x,y)<\lcm(a,b)$. I had tried to prove it but I am unable to do it. I am a little weak with number theory. Is the statement true? It would also be helpful if someone provided a graph of $\lcm$ function and help me to know how $\lcm$ varies with $x,y$?

Comment: You ask for strict inequality: $\text{lcm}(x,y)<\text{lcm}(a,b)$. But even if $x<a$ and $y<b$ one can get equality, say for $x=2$, $y=3$, $a=6$ and $b=6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ \begin{align} x\mid a\mid{\rm lcm}(a,b)\\ y\mid b \mid{\rm lcm}(a,b)\end{align} \Rightarrow\, {\rm lcm}(x,y)\mid  {\rm lcm}(a,b)$

using that: $\,\ x,y\mid m\iff {\rm lcm}(x,y)\mid m,\,$ the [LCM Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242)

Comment: I did not say $x,y|a,b$ ,I said $x|a$ and $y|b$.

Comment: @Kishalay I clarified what was meant (it uses only your hypothesis).