# Let $a\mid bc $ then prove or disprove $a\mid (a,b)c$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Prove or disprove:

Let $a\mid bc$ then $a\mid (a,b)c$

Here is my approach, but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly or efficiently.

Let $a\mid bc$. It follows that either

1. $a\mid b$ Proof: $b=ar, a\mid bc => (ar)c = a \rightarrow a(rc)=a \rightarrow a|a(rc)$
2. $a\mid c$.

Since $rc$ is an integer. $a\mid bc$. Similar for $(2). a|c $

Let $a\mid (a,b)c$.

Using: the definition of $\gcd(a,b)=1=ax+by$ if $\exists x,y \in Z$

then we can rewrite it as $a\mid dc$. This is as far as I go. I can't manipulate it so that I show that $a\mid (a,b)c$. Does this mean that I would have to disprove $a\mid bc$ then $a\mid (a,b)c$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is (a,b) the gcd? If yes, then try out some examples. How can it maybe go wrong?

Comment: $a|bc$ does not imply that $a|b$ or $a|c$. For example, $6|2 \cdot 3$, but $6$ divides neither $2$ nor $3$. The implication holds if $a$ is prime though. More generally, $a|bc$ implies $a|c$ if $\textrm{gcd}\left(a,b\right) = 1$.

Comment: @Amjad (a,b) is the gcd. I used $gcd(a,b) = gcd(15,20) = 5$. I inserted it into $a|(a,b)c$ and it turned into $5c = 15q$. The only way this works out is if $c = 3q$, but if it doesn't this doesn't work out, I believe.

Comment: @SamStreeter My wording was off. I didn't mean to say that a|b or b|c was implied. I just knew that a|b can be a property of $a|bc$. So if $a$ is relatively prime is $a|(a,b)c$ able to be proved by just using $a|bc => a|c$ if $gcd(a,b)=1$ then rewriting as $a|(a,b)c = a|1c. $?

Comment: @HawaiianRolls Sure, the result you're after follows from the result I have stated in the special case where $a$ is relatively prime to $b$, but this doesn't help with the general solution. However, the answers below, as you have seen, give a nice and simple proof by Bézout's identity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm really confused about your solution. $a\mid bc$ doesn't imply that either $a\mid b$ or $a\mid c$ unless $a$ is a prime number. Anyway, the statement you try to prove/disprove is true. You can write $(a,b)=ka+lb$ when $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $(a,b)c=kac+lbc$. $a$ divides $a$ and so $a\mid $. Also $a\mid bc$ which implies $a\mid lbc$. And hence $a$ divides the sum $kac+lbc=(a,b)c$.

Comment: I did not know that you can have a divide the sum and the conclude that a|(a,b)c because of it. Thanks

Comment: If $a|x$ and $a|y$ then also $a|(x+y)$, that is what I used in the last step. It is very easy to prove.

Comment: Yeah just did it now. Thanks for your help Mark.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in your proof is that knowing that $a|bc$ does not imply that $a|b$ or $a|c$.

Hint: Use the fact that the $\gcd(a,b)$ can be written as follows:
$$
\gcd(a,b)=ax+by
$$
for some integers $x$ and $y$.  By substituting this into the expression $\gcd(a,b)c$, you get
$$
\gcd(a,b)c=acx+bcy.
$$ 
Both of the terms $acx$ and $bcy$ are divisible by $a$ (but for different reasons).  Can you work from here?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think Mark explained the different reasons. I got to where you were on my notebook, I just couldn't figure out why $acx + bcy$ were divisible by $a$. I did not know you use the fact that $a$ divides the sums as proof that $a|(a,b)c$.

Comment: Note that if you haven't proved it yet, you might need to prove the claim that if $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$, then $a\mid(b+c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Try $\dfrac aA=\dfrac bB=(a,b)\implies(A,B)=1\ \  \  \  (1)$

$a|bc\implies A|Bc\implies A|c$  by $(1)$

Now $(a,b)c=dc$ is divisible by $dA=a$

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to pay attention when you said *if $a|bc$ then $a|b$ or $a|c$* **this is not true unless $a$ is prime**. Consider this counter example: $6|2 \times 3$.

For the proposition you claimed, you may need to be familiar with this result:

> $a|bc \to \frac{a}{(a,b)}|c$

Using this fact, consider the following:

$\frac{a}{(a,b)}|c \to c = \frac{a}{(a,b)} k \to c(a,b) = ak \to a|(a,b)c$

Now, can you prove this generalized version of your result:

> $a|bc \to a|(a,b)(a,c)$

Answer (score 0):

$a\:\!\:\!|\:\!\:\!(a,b)c\color{#c00}{\overset{\rm D}{=}}(ac,bc)\!\!\!\!\color{#0c0}{\overset{\rm U\!\!}{\iff}}\!\! a\:\!|\:\!ac,bc\!\!\iff\!\! a\:\!|\:\!bc\,$ by  $\rm \color{#0c0}U\! =\! $ [Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198801/242),
$\rm\color{#c00}D\! =\! $ [Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242).

**Remark** $ $ Other proofs using Bezout are essentially  Bezout-based proofs of the gcd distributive law so they are less general - they don't work in domains like $\:\!\Bbb Z[x]\:\!$ and $\:\!\Bbb Q[y,z]$ where Bezout fails, e.g. $\,(x,2) = 1 = (y,z)\,$ but these gcds cannot be written as linear combinations, else, e.g. $x\!f\!+\!2g\!=\!1\overset{x\ =\ 0}\Longrightarrow 2g(0)=1\Rightarrow 2\mid 1\,$ in $\Bbb Z\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow\,;\,$ ditto for $(y,z)=1$ by eval at $\,y\!=\!0\!=\!z$.