# Why are we using GCD here in the given problems?

Tags: arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

There are two questions where I am having difficulty to solve. One of the question asks us the calculate the minimum number of square tiles required to cover a floor of dimension 247 ft x 209 ft. The particularly confusing part arises when we are not familiar with the intuition behind the calculation. Why would I really need to have square tiles to calculate a GCD is yet unknown to me here. Secondly, in another problem where we are required to find the number of wires of 22cm required to reach a length of 1m so that there is not wire that is left over also demands the usage of GCD. I am yet unfamiliar with how to solve these problems. Why GCD is being used particularly is  unknown.

Comment: The side length $d$ of the tile must exactly divide both $247$ and $209$ for an exact fit. But $\,d\mid a,b\iff d\mid \gcd(a,b)\ $ by the [gcd universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198801/242). Such *tiling*  problems are one of the common geometrical motivations of the gcd.

Comment: Yes but why is it the minimum number of tiles here?

Comment: @BillDubuque What about the next problem? Secondly, can you explain it more analytically that mathematics. Can you write a better answer?

Comment: If you decrease the tile size then you need more tiles. The second problem seems to be incorrectly stated. Please check it.  It's not clear what you mean by "more analytically...".