# Proof: Suppose $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. Then a = gcd(a,b) iff $a|b$.

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

So I've constructed a proof for this answer and I'm having trouble completeing it. To prove iff statements we need to prove the statment $P \rightarrow Q$ then $Q \rightarrow P$. Convert the statement into a conditional statement then prove the conditional statement and prove its converse.

If $a = \textrm{gcd}(a,b)$ then $a|b$. Assume $a = \textrm{gcd}(a,b)$ by definition of $\textrm{gcd}$ $a$ is a divisor of both $a$ and $b$. So by definition of divides $a|b$ must be true.

Prove conversely, Assume $a|b$ by definition of divides $a(n)=b$ and from our definition of $\textrm{gcd}$ then b(k) = a for some integer $n$ and $k$. Consider, $a(n)(k) = a = n(k) = 1$ by the identity property we know that $(n)(k)$ are both 1. Considering that $n=1$ and $k =1$ and $a$ divides $b$ then...

Is the above statement correct? What does $n = 1$ and
$k = 1$ tell me about about $a$?

Comment: How do you reach $b(k) = a$ from the definition of gcd? Try $a = 2, b = 4$

Comment: $n$ is what? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews some integer n and k.

Comment: @Manifoldski if a = gcd(a,b) then a|b and b|a?

Comment: No, it seems like you are confusing $lcm(a,b)$ (least common multiple, the smallest $c$ such that $b\mid c$ and $a\mid c$) with $gcd(a,b)$(the largest $d$ such that $d \mid a$ and $d\mid b$)

Comment: No, "Suppose $a,b\in n.$" In your title. What is $n?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the natural numbers. I can see it in black board bold, latex.

Comment: @Ziggy Usually, it should be capital $\mathbb N.$ My browser did not make it clear it was not just $n.$

Comment: As [here (case $r=0),\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242) 
if $\,a\mid b\,$ then $\,a,b\,$ and $\,a\,$ have the same set $S$ of common divisors so they have the same *greatest* common divisor $(= \max S = \gcd(a) = a)\ \ $

Comment: The above actually proves *both* directions since the converse holds too, i.e.  with $\rm cd = $ common divisors, $\gcd(a,b) = a\,\overset{\!\rm\color{#c00}U}\Rightarrow\, {\rm cd}(a,b) = {\rm cd}(a)\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid b\,$ (by $\,a\in {\rm cd}(a)= {\rm cd}(a,b)\Rightarrow a\mid b),\ $ where we used that $\,d\mid \gcd(a,b)\!\iff\! d\mid a,b,\,$ i.e. $\rm\color{#c00}U=$ [gcd universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198801/242).  But w/o knowing this property,  for this easy direction it's simpler to just use $\,a=\gcd(a,b)\mid b\,$ as you did.