# Prove the LCM (Least Common Multiple).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$

Let $m,n$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$.  The least common multiple ($\lcm$) of $m,n$ is the smallest natural number $x$, such that $m \mid x$ and $n \mid x$. Prove that the $\lcm$ of $m,n$ is equal to ${m,n\over \gcd(m,n)}$.

Here is my proof so far:

${m,n\over \gcd(m,n)}$ is a common multiple of *m* and *n*.

I am assuming that $q_m$ and $q_n$ are coprime.

If $m = q_m \gcd(m,n)$ & $n = q_n \gcd(m,n)$, then ${m,n\over \gcd(m,n)}$ becomes ${q_m \gcd(m,n)q_n \gcd(m,n)\over \gcd(m,n)}$ which equals $q_m q_n \gcd(m,n)$.

So, $m \mid q_m \gcd(m,n)q_n$ & $n \mid q_n \gcd(m,n)q_m$.

Taking $x$ into consideration, $m \mid x$ and $n \mid x$, $x = k_1 m$ and $x = k_2 n$ which is $x = k_1 q_m \gcd(m,n)$ and $x = k_2 q_n \gcd(m,n)$.  Since $x$ is equal to itself, we set these equal to each other:

$k_1 q_m \gcd(m,n) = k_2 q_n \gcd(m,n)$

$k_1 q_m = k_2 q_n$

${k_1 \over q_n} = {k_2 \over q_m}$.

So now I'm not really sure where to go from this point.  It doesn't really feel like I've proven anything at all...

**Update**
After using the suggestions below and amending my homework, I turned it in to my professor and he said absolutely none of what I said made any sense and refused to give me any homework points.  Without a doubt in my mind I believe that my answer was correct, or at least made sense, so I am leaving this question up here to assist other users.  I'm just forewarning you that my professor made it fairly clear to me that none of what I had written made any sense so please use this problem with caution.  Thank you to everyone that helped me better understand this proof, I really appreciated it.

Comment: I changed $gcd$ to $\gcd$, $lcm$ to $\operatorname{lcm}$, and $a\ | \ b$ to $a\mid b$.  That is standard $\TeX$ usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ m,n\mid x\!\iff\! mn\mid mx,nx\!\iff\! mn\mid\overbrace{(mx,nx)}^{\textstyle  (m,n)x}\!$ $\rm\iff\! \overbrace{mn/(m,n)}^{\textstyle \ell}\mid x$

Let $\rm\:x = \ell\:$ in $\,(\Leftarrow)\,$ to get $\rm\:m,n\mid \ell,\:$ i.e. $\rm\:\ell\:$ is a *common multiple* of $\rm\:m,n,\:$ necessarily the *least* common multiple, since $(\Rightarrow)$ shows $\rm\:m,n\mid x\:\Rightarrow\:\ell\mid x\:\Rightarrow\:\ell\le x.$

**Remark** $\ $ That $\rm\: m,n\mid x\iff \ell\mid x\,$ is a *definition* of $\rm\,{\rm lcm}(m,n)\,$ in more general rings since - as  above - it implies that $\,\ell\,$  is a common multiple of $\rm\,a,b\,$ that is *divisibly* least, i.e. it divides every common multiple. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3149/242) for this *universal* approach to LCMs and GCDs.

Comment: Above we used the [GCD Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242) $\,\rm (mx,nx) = (m,n)x,\,$ (which [ends up being](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/199178/242) the distributive law for integers if you replace the gcd by its Bezout linear representation).

Answer (score 4):

When $m,n$ are coprime $\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}\lcm(m,n)=mn$, now consider $dm,dn$ (every pair of numbers may be written this way) $\lcm(dm,dn)=d \lcm(m,n)=dmn = \frac{(dm)(dn)}{d} = \frac{(dm)(dn)}{\gcd(dm,dn)}$.

Comment: Note that this argument assumes (w/o proof) the law $\,{\rm lcm}(dm,dn) = d\,{\rm lcm}(m,n).\,$ This may yield a *circular proof* in many contexts, since often that law is proved by replacing lcm by gcd using the sought result here. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242) for a proof of the lcm distributive law that avoids such circularity.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost at the end! We have $k_1q_m=k_2q_n$.  But $q_m$ and $q_n$ are **relatively prime**. That will tell us something about $k_1$, and therefore about the size of $x$.