# Relation of common divisors leading to integer results

Tags: elementary-number-theory, intuition, divisibility

When dividing an integer $a$ by 3 and 7 both results in an integer answer, I intuitively feel  that $a/A$ with $A=21$ would also be integer, which seems related to the fact that $3\times7=21$.

However, for an integer $b$ that divided by 4 and 6 would result in an integer answer it seems to be that $b/A$ with $A=12$ is integer as well.

My question is: **is there a way to determine $A$ based on a multiplication of the two known integer divisions?**

From the two examples that I gave I can think of this $A=\frac{x\times y}{gcd(x,y)}$, where $x$ and $y$ are the two numbers that result in integer answers. But I don't have a solid reason to believe this is generally true.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. $A = \frac{a\times b}{gcd(a,b)}$

This is usually known as [Least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_multiple) or lowest common multiple.

Answer (score 1):

By [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezout's_identity) $ $ for  the gcd: $\,\ ja+kb \ =\ (a,b)\,$ for some $\,j,k,\in\Bbb Z.\,$ Therefore

$\phantom{\rm or}\ \ \ a,b\mid c\,\Rightarrow\, ab\mid ac,bc\,\Rightarrow\, ab\mid jac+kbc=(a,b)c\,\Rightarrow\,ab/(a,b)\mid c $

${\rm or}\ \ \  a,b\mid c\,\Rightarrow\, ab\mid ac,bc\,\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\, ab\mid\ (ac,\,bc)\ =\ (a,b)c\,\Rightarrow\,ab/(a,b)\mid c $

Proof $\,2\,$ uses the [GCD universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) $\,j\mid k,n\!\color{#c00}\iff\! j\mid (k,n),\,$ and, furthermore, it replaces the  Bezout Identity by the [GCD Distributive Law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242)

The  arrows reverse, [which shows](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/235209/242) $\ {\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab/\gcd(a,b)=\,$ [least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_multiple) of $\,a,b.$