# how to prove lcm divides any common multiple from definition of lcm(a,b) = (a*b)/gcd(a,b)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

So the goal is to prove that the $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ divides any multiple of of $a$ and $b$.
Suppose there is  some integer $c$ such that  $a|c$ and  $b|c$ but I want to prove $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)|c$ also. 
I got that $$\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=\frac{(a\cdot b)}{\gcd(a,b)}$$ and I want to see how we could show $$\frac{(a*b)}{\gcd(a,b)}\bigg| \, c$$ Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: It's the direction $(\Rightarrow)$ in the equiavlences in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/235209/242) in the first linked dupe. See the others for background and motivation..

Comment: Please don't change the question at this point. If you have a related question then pose a new question.

Answer (score -1):

**WARNING: This answer is INCORRECT.  See comments for what mistakes I am making**

Firstly we know that some multiple of $a$ and $b$ can be represented by $kab$ where $k$ is some integer, and thus is divisible by $ab$.

We need to show that $lcm(a,b) \vert ab$. Since $gcd(a,b)$ would be some integer, and that $lcm(a,b) gcd(a,b) = ab$, it is obvious.

Therefore any multiple of $ab$ is divisible by $lcm(a,b)$.

Comment: The claim in the first sentence is false.

Comment: I wonder, why it is not true that $ a \vert c $ and $ b \vert c $ means $ (ab) \vert c$ and therefore $c = kab$ ? (I know that maybe gcd(a,b) is not 1 but c is some multiple of a **and** b)

Comment: e.g. $\,2,4\mid 4\,$ but not $\,2\cdot 4\mid 4.\ $ Your claim is true $\iff \gcd(a,b) = 1\ \ $

Comment: Thanks. I thought that multiple of a **and** b means that $c = k a ^m b^n$ where k,m,n are some integers......