# Proof 1 that $ab = \operatorname{lcm}(a,b) \operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$ on Pr$\infty$f Wiki

Tags: proof-explanation, gcd-and-lcm

Here is the theorem they prove:

> $$|ab| = \operatorname{lcm}(a,b) \operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$$
>
> where
>
> - $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ denotes the lowest common multiple of $a$ and $b$.
> - $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$ denotes the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Proof 1 is below (in case the original site changes). I have highlighted the end part that I don't understand in red.

> It is sufficient to prove that $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) \operatorname{gcd}(a,b) = ab$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.
>
> $d = \operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$
>
> $\implies d | ab$
>
> $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}: ab = dn$
>
> $d | a \land d | b$
>
> $\implies \exists u,v \in \mathbb{Z}:a  =du \land b = dv$
>
> $\implies dub = dn \land adv = dn$
>
> $\implies n=bu \land n = av$
>
> $\implies a | n \land b | n$
>
> Now we have $a|m \land b | m \implies m = ar=bs$.
>
> Also, by Bézout's Lemma we have $d = ax + by$.
>
> So:
> \begin{align}md &= axm + bym \\ &= bsax + arby \\ &= ab(sx + ry) \\ &= dn (sx + ry) \end{align}
>
> So:
>
> $m = n(sx + ry)$
>
> Thus:
>
> $n|m \implies n \leq |m|$
>
> while:
>
> $\color{red}{ab = dn = \operatorname{gcd}(a,b) \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)}$
>
> as required.
>
> $\blacksquare$

I get that we are meant to conclude that $n = \operatorname{lcm}$, but I don't yet see why the workup to this point entails that $n$ must be the least common multiple.

Comment: We know by "⟹a|n∧b|n" that $n$ is a common multiple.  And we just proved that for any *other* common multiple, $m$, that $n \le m$.  That means that by definition $n$ is the least common multiple.

Comment: The proof shows $\,n := ab/d = {\rm \color{#c00}L\color{#0a0}CM}(a,b)\,$ by first showing that $\,n\,$ is a $\rm\color{#0a0}{Common}$ multiple of $\,a,b,\,$ necessarily the $\rm\color{#c00}{Least}$ common multiple since it divides every common multiple $\,m.\ $ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/235209/242) in the linked dupe for a clearer presentation.