# How to show that $\displaystyle [a,b,c] = \frac{abc}{(ab,bc,ca)}$ without prime factorization?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, least-common-multiple, gcd-and-lcm

I think this has been asked before, but I couldn't find it on math.SE. I googled it too, but I wasn't lucky enough to find it there either. So, here's the problem:

Demonstrate that for any $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$: $$\displaystyle [a,b,c] = \frac{abc}{(ab,bc,ca)}$$

It's not very hard to verify this equality once we know the prime factorization theorem. We can set:

$$a = p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$$
$$b = p_1^{\beta_1} p_2^{\beta_2} \cdots p_n^{\beta_n}$$
$$c = p_1^{\gamma_1} p_2^{\gamma_2}\cdots p_n^{\gamma_n}$$

Where $0 \leq \alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i $ and $p_i$ is a prime number that appears in the prime factorization of at least one of the three.

Therefore, the equality is true if and only if this equality holds for all $1 \leq i \leq n$:

$$\min\{\alpha_i+\beta_i,\beta_i+\gamma_i,\gamma_i+\alpha_i\} + \max\{\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i\} = \alpha_i+\beta_i+\gamma_i$$

It's very easy to verify this equality. Therefore, the theorem holds if we are allowed to use prime factorization theorem.

How can we demonstrate that the equality is true without using the prime factorization theorem?

Comment: Maybe this identity is true in a GCD domain?

Comment: @math.n00b No, a GCD domain is any domain where any two elements not both $\,0\,$ have a gcd. A Bezout Domain is a GCD domain where a Bezout identity exists for every gcd, which need not be true generally, e.g. $\,\Bbb Q[x,y]\,$ is UFD so GCD, and $\,\gcd(x,y) = 1\,$ but $\,x f + y\, g \ne 1,\,$ else $\, 0 = 1\,$ by eval @ $\,x,y = 0,0.\ $ The proof in my answer works in any gcd domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that we can wirte $[a,b,c]=[[a,b],c]$ and let say $k=[a,b]=\dfrac {ab}{(a,b)}$

$[k,c]=\dfrac {kc}{(k,c)}=\dfrac {abc}{(a,b)(k,c)}$ and notice that $r(x,y)=(rx,ry)$

$$=\dfrac {abc}{((a,b)k,(a,b)c)}$$
$$=\dfrac {abc}{(ab,(a,b)c)} $$
$$=\dfrac {abc}{(ab,(ac,bc))}$$
$$=\dfrac {abc}{(ab,ac,bc)}$$

**Note:** $(a,b),[a,b]$ stand for $\gcd(a,b)$ and $\text{lcm}[a,b]$ respectively.

Comment: $${\rm i.e.}\ \ \ [[a,b],c] = \dfrac{\color{#c00}{[a,b]}\ c}{([a,b],c)}=\color{#c00}{\dfrac{ab}{(a,b)}}\dfrac{c}{([a,b],c)} = \dfrac{abc}{(ab,(a,b)c)}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$  This can be proved symmetrically, without using the gcd * lcm identity, by using only the universal properties of gcd and lcm, and the distributive law for gcd - see my answer.

Comment: That was 9 years ago sir, I guess I had seen your answer.

Answer (score 9):

A proof is *mechanical* using [*universal properties*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) $\rm\,\color{#c00}{(UP)\ of\ lcm,gcd}\,$ and $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{duality}$

**Theorem** $\,\ {\rm lcm}(a,b,c)\, =\, \dfrac{abc}{(bc,ca,ab)}$

$\begin{align} {\bf Proof}\quad\ \ \ {\rm lcm}(a,b,c)&\mid\ n\\ 
\iff a,b,c&\mid\ n,\ \ \text{by}\,\color{#c00}{\text{  UP lcm}}\\ 
\iff\quad abc&\mid\, nbc,nca,nab,\ \ \ \ \text{by}\ \ \rm\color{#0a0}{duality},\ see\ below\\ 
\iff\quad abc&\mid\! (nbc,nca,nab),\ \ \text{by}\,\color{#c00}{\text{  UP gcd}}\\
\iff\quad abc&\mid\, n(bc,ca,ab) \\ 
\iff\ \ \dfrac{abc}{(bc,ca,ab)}&\:\!\ \Big|\ n\end{align}$

**Note** $ $ The [innate symmetry governing the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/717775/242) is the involution $\ x\to x' = abc/x\,$ which highlights the *duality* $ $ lcm$' =$  gcd,$\ $ gcd$' =$ lcm, $ $ that arises from $\, \color{#0a0}{x\mid y\iff y'\mid x'},\,$ viz.

$\qquad\qquad \begin{eqnarray} 
{\rm lcm}(a,b,c) &=&\, {\rm lcm}(a,b,c)''\\[.2em]
&=&\, {\gcd(a',b',c')'}\\[.1em]
&=&\,  \dfrac{abc}{\gcd(a',b',c')}\\[.1em]
&=&\, \dfrac{abc}{\gcd(bc,ca,ab)}\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: You are following me ha :), nice answer.

Comment: This is a very good answer. I like how elementary and simple it is and it's a pity that I failed to reason like this on my own. :| Is it possible to generalize the concept of least common divisor to other rings?

Comment: @math.n00b Yes, see the [universal definitions](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) of gcd and lcm, which I have implicitly used in the above proof, viz. $\,a,b,c\mid n\iff {\rm lcm}(a,b,c)\mid n,\,$ and $\ abc\mid i,j,k\iff abc\mid (i,j,k).\ \ $

Comment: @math.noob I've expanded the answer to highlight the innate gcd,lcm duality.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Your answer was pretty straightforward and understandable from the beginning. By the way, may I ask how you change your font style and color? I couldn't find it in the options available in my toolbar when I write a post. Are we allowed to use html codes in math.SE?

Comment: @math.n00b I use the `\color` command in MathJax, right-click on it and select "show math as / TeX commands" to see the source. Note that the two blue texts denote hyperlinks (to prior answers), which may be highlighted differently depending on your browser config.

Comment: what is n here?

Comment: @f.jalili $\ n\,$ is any integer. If $a$ and $b$ have the same multiples, i.e. $\, a\mid n\iff b\mid n\,$ for any $n$ then $\,a\mid b\mid a\,$ so $\,a=b\,$ for $\,a,b > 0.\ \ $

Comment: Does your **Theorem** say this?? This: for any positive integers $a,b,c$ we have

$\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)=\dfrac{abc \operatorname{gcd}(a,b,c)} {\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)\operatorname{gcd}(b,c)\operatorname{gcd}(c,a)}$

Comment: I didn't understand your notation in your theorem

Comment: @James No, that's not the question here. Rather, that is proved in the second equality [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2366155/242).  $(a.b,c)$ is standard  notation for $\gcd(a,b,c)$ in number theory. If you have question about *that* proof please ask under it - not here.

Comment: @James I added a [Remark](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2366155/242) to that answer that may make the proof clearer. Please feel welcome to ask further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @James We can also prove [your identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3554077/242) using unique prime factorizations as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/853930/242). Then it boils down to the following equality on exponents $\ \gamma = (\alpha+\beta+\gamma)+\alpha-(\alpha+\beta+\alpha).\ $ See also [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2386373/242)