# Least Common Multiple Identity Proof (Andrews Number Theory, Problem 2.4.12)

Tags: number-theory, self-learning, gcd-and-lcm

I'm having some trouble manipulating these expressions to reach the following conclusion:

> Let $d_1 = \gcd(a,b), d_2 = \gcd(b,c), d_3 =\gcd(c,a), D = \gcd(a,b,c), L=\lcm(a,b,c)$. Prove that:
>
> $$L = \frac{abcD}{d_1d_2d_3}$$

Using some previous exercises in the book, I can rewrite $d_1, d_2, d_3, D$ and $L$ as:

$$d_1 = t_1^{\alpha_1}...t_v^{\alpha_v}$$
$$d_2 = t_1^{\beta_1}...t_v^{\beta_v}$$
$$d_3 = t_1^{\gamma_1}...t_v^{\gamma_v}$$
$$D = t_1^{\zeta_1}...t_v^{\zeta_v}$$
$$L = t_1^{\mu_1}...t_v^{\mu_v}$$

where each $t_i$ is a factor of at least one of $a,b,c$, and $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$, $\gamma_i$, and $\zeta_i$ are the smallest powers for their corresponding $\gcd$ (e.g. $\alpha_1$ is the smaller of the two powers of factor $t_i$ that $a$ and $b$ have). Conversely, $\mu_i$ is the greatest exponent between $a,b,c$. It is here that I'm getting stuck. I've substituted these expressions into the equation for $L$, but something about the manipulation is throwing me off. I'm trying to logically work out what, say, $t_i^{\frac{\alpha_i+\beta_i+\gamma_i}{\mu_i}}$ is, but going from that to demonstrating the equality is not computing. Any suggestions would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: I think that maybe drawing a Venn diagram for three sets, which will represent the numbers $a,b,c$ would help you. Interpret intersections in the diagram as taking $\gcd$. Choose variable names for each piece of the diagram that doesn't contain any piece inside. Write the variables in the problem as products of these variables.

Comment: Indeed, the identity in question is a multiplicative example of the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\text{lcm}(a,b,c) = \frac{a \cdot b \cdot c \cdot \gcd(a,b,c)}{\gcd(a,b)\gcd(b,c)\gcd(a,c)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386373/prove-textlcma-b-c-fraca-cdot-b-cdot-c-cdot-gcda-b-c-gcda-b) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Coperatorname%7Blcm%7D(a%2Cb%2Cc)%3D%5Cfrac%7Babc%5Cgcd(a%2Cb%2Cc)%7D%7B%5Cgcd(a%2Cb)%5Cgcd(b%2Cc)%5Cgcd(c%2Ca)%7D%24&p=1). Note the [accepted answer](/a/2386382/602049) there uses the prime factorizations, similar to what you're doing. ...

Comment: (cont.) Note I found that question as being listed as a duplicate of [Prove that $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)=\frac{abc \operatorname{gcd}(a,b,c)} {\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)\operatorname{gcd}(b,c)\operatorname{gcd}(c,a)}$](/q/3554077), with this also listing [Prove $\gcd(a,b) \gcd(a,c) \gcd(b,c) \,\text{lcm} (a,b,c)^2=$ $\text{lcm}(a,b)\,\text{lcm}(a,c) \,\text{lcm}(b,c) \gcd(a,b,c)^2$](/q/2365799) and [Prove that: $\gcd[a,b,c]=\frac{abc.\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)}{\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\operatorname{lcm}(a,c)\operatorname{lcm}(b,c)}$](/q/3408968) as additional duplicates. ...

Comment: (cont.)  In addition, there's the AoPS thread [How to prove this identity ?](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1461734p8443251).

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut:

It is sufficient to show that the equality holds, for **any** prime number $p$ that happens to occur in the prime factorizations of any of $a,b,c.$

Assume that :

- $a$ contains $p^A$ in it's prime factorization.
- $b$ contains $p^B$ in it's prime factorization.
- $c$ contains $p^C$ in it's prime factorization.

Note that one or more of $A,B,C$ may equal $(0)$.

Since the computations of $d_1, d_2,$ and $d_3$ are **cyclic**, you can assume, without loss of generality that $A \leq B \leq C.$

Then, solely with respect to the prime number $p$, the assertion is equivalent to asserting that

$$\frac{p^A \times p^B \times p^C \times p^A}{p^A \times p^B \times p^A} = p^C.$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).