# Prove that $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)=\frac{abc \operatorname{gcd}(a,b,c)} {\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)\operatorname{gcd}(b,c)\operatorname{gcd}(c,a)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> Prove that for any positive integers $a,b,c$ we have
>
> $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)=\dfrac{abc \operatorname{gcd}(a,b,c)} {\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)\operatorname{gcd}(b,c)\operatorname{gcd}(c,a)}$

To prove this, I used this: for two positive integers $a,b$ is $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$
 but I could do nothing, can you help?

Comment: But that Lemma is already linked in the first dupe.

Comment: We can also prove it using unique prime factorizations as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/853930/242). Then it boils down to the following equality on exponents $\ \gamma = (\alpha+\beta+\gamma)+\alpha-(\alpha+\beta+\alpha).\ $ See also [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2386373/242)

Comment: It is similar to the Inclusion-Exclusion principle for three sets.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Yes, inclusion-exclusion is one common way to prove identities between gcd and lcm. Some of these identities are [already discussed here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=gcd+lcm+inclusion)