# Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and $I, J$ ideals in $R$. Prove that $IJ = I \cap J$ if and only if $I+J =R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and $I, J$ ideals in $R$. Prove that $IJ = I \cap J$ if and only if $I+J =R$.

I can't prove that $IJ = I \cap J$ implies $I+J = R$. The rest I can prove. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you check the problem statement, it seems that if $I$ or $J$ is the $0$-ideal, then $IJ=I\cap J$, but $I+J\not=R$.

Comment: Hint: Think about the integers: suppose $I$ and $J$ are nonzero ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $I=\langle p\rangle$ and $J=\langle q\rangle$.  Then $IJ=\langle pq\rangle$ and $I\cap J=\langle\text{lcm}(p,q)\rangle$.  Then $IJ=I\cap J$ iff $pq=\text{lcm}(p,q)$.  $pq=\text{lcm}(p,q)$ iff $\gcd(p,q)=1$, so $1\in\langle p\rangle+\langle q\rangle$.

Comment: Most proofs for $\,\Bbb Z\,$ generalize to  PIDs, e.g. [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1136611/242) for a quick one.

Comment: Hi, I don't quite understand how to generalise it to PID. Isn't this the right proof?

Comment: @Aha $ $ Translate via: $\ (i)\supseteq (j)\iff i\mid j,\,$ and $\,(i)+(j) = (\gcd(i,j))\,$ and $\,(i)\cap(j) = ({\rm lcm}(i,j))\ \ $ Note you need to ping a username or no one will be notified by your comment.

Comment: @MichaelBurr , and Bill_Dubuque , would any one of you please post an answer so I can at least upvote it? Thanks