# Divisibility proof with GCD condition

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> Suppose $a|m$,  $b|m$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. Prove, without appealing to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, that $ab|m$.

I know that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ means they are relatively prime. I also know that $a|m$ means $m=as$ and that $b|m$ means $m=bt$ and lastly that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ means $1=ax+by$. I just have no idea what to do next. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416335/

Comment: Multiply by $m$ and argue that $ab$ divides each term of the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then there exists integers $s$ and $t$ such that $as + bt = 1$. If $a|m$ and $b|m$ then there exists integers $S$ and $T$ such that $m = Sa = Tb.

\begin{align}
   as + bt &= 1\\
   mas + mbt &= m\\
   Tbas + Sabt &= m\\
   ab(Ts + St) &= m\\
\end{align}

It follows that $ab | m$