# Problem in Modulo Operation in prime factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> Let's consider $a_1$ and $a_2$:
> \begin{align*}
> a_1&=a(p)\\
> a_2&=a(q)
> \end{align*}
> $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the orders of $a_1$ and $a_2$ in the rings $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\mathbb Z_q$.
> $$a_1^r(p) = a^r(p)=1,$$
> because $a^r=1(pq)$. Since $r_1$ is the order of $a_1$ in $\mathbb Z_p$, the number $r$ is a multiple of $r_1$. The same reasoning for $\mathbb Z_q$ gives us $r$ is a multiple of $r_2$.

##### **Definition of variables**

1. $N = p \cdot q $, where $p$ and $q$ are primes
2. $gcd(a,N) = 1$ that is $a$ and $N$ are co-primes.
3. Periodic function is described as$ Fa(x) = a^x mod N  $
4. $a^r \equiv 1 \pmod N$ that is $r$ is the period of the Fa(x)
   Now my question is How the sixth line, How is it coming?

**How does $\,a^r \equiv 1\pmod{\!pq}\,$ lead to $\,a_1^r (p) = a^r(p) = 1$?**

Comment: Precisely *what* is not clear? (it's not even clear which line you count as "sixth")

Comment: Are you asking how they deduced $r$ is a multiple of $r_1?$ If so that's an immediate consequence of the [Order Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242), i.e. if $\,a\,$ has order $k$ then $\,a^{\large j} = 1\iff k\mid j\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I cant understand how a^r ≡ 1(mod pq) is leading to                 a1^r  (p) = a^r(p) = 1 ??

Comment: @UzumakiSaptarshi I added an answer to that.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). To help you get started, I have typed the text from your picture. (So if you're satisfied with the result, you can remove the picture. Of course, you'll need to reformulate the part about sixth line.)

Comment: Last link is rotted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cant understand how $\,a^r \equiv 1\pmod{pq}$ is leading to $\,a_1^r (p) = a^r(p) = 1$

Recall that [congruences persist mod $\,\rm\color{#c00}{factors}\,$ of the modulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/883060/242).

So $\!\bmod \color{#c00}pq\!:\ 1\equiv a^{\large r}\Rightarrow\bmod \color{#c00}p\!:\ 1\equiv a^{\large r}\equiv a_1^{\large r}\ $ by $\,a\equiv a_1\,$ and the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

Hence since $\,a_1\,$ has order $\,r_1\,$ we infer $\, r_1\mid r\,$ by the [Order Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242).

Similarly $\, r_2\mid r,\ $ hence $\,{\rm lcm}(r_1,r_2)\mid r\,$ by the [LCM Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242),

Furthermore, [recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1136525/242) that $\,{\rm lcm}(r_1,r_2) = r_1 r_2\,$ when $\,\gcd(r_1,r_2) = 1$.

Comment: what does r1 | r mean?   and Could you please give some more description on the phrase "Congruences persist mod factors of the modulus". I cant quite get my head around it.

Comment: @Uzumaki  $\ a\mid b\,$ means $a$ divides $b,\,$ i.e. $\,an = b\,$ for some integer $n.\ $  Please see  the linked post for a proof of said persistence.