# If $a \equiv b \mod m$, $a \equiv b \mod n$, and $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $a \equiv b \mod mn$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If $a \equiv b \mod m$, $a \equiv b \mod n$, and $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $a \equiv b \mod mn$.

So I know that $mk=a-b$ and $nj=a-b$ for some $k,j \in \mathbb{Z}$ and that $\gcd(m,n)=1$ can be represented as $mx+ny=1$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I know to prove this I must end with an equation looking like this: $(mn)f=a-b$ for some $f \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I'm just not connecting something in the middle. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) in the dupe for a handful of ways to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}a-b&=(a-b)(mx+ny)\\&=(a-b)mx+(a-b)ny\\&=njmx+mkny\\&=mn(jx+ky).\end{align}

Comment: i.e. $\,m,n\mid c\Rightarrow mn\mid mc,nc\Rightarrow\,mn\mid c(\color{#c00}{mx\!+\!ny})= c\color{#c00}{\gcd(m,n)},\,$ so $\,mn/\gcd(m,n)\mid c,\,$ for $\,c = a\!-\!b\,$ here. This is the common Bezout-basied proof of ${\rm lcm}(m,n) = mn/\gcd(m,n)\,$ in the case $\gcd(m,n)=1,\,$ already posted here hundreds of times, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/194978/242). Please strive to not post yet more dupe answers.