# If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a$ and $b$ divide $c$, then so does $ab$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Using divisibility theorems, prove that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a|c$ and $b|c$, then $ab|c$.

This is pretty clear by UPF, but I'm having some trouble proving it using divisibility theorems. I was looking at [this Math.SE problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m%20), and if this could be proven, then the solution would follow immediately.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that $a s +b t =1$. Hence $c a s +c b  t =c$. Now since $a \vert c$ and $b \vert c$ there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $c = m a$ and $c= n b$. Hence $n b a s  + m a b  t =c$. Since $a b $ divides the entire left hand side, it must also divide the right hand side.

Comment: Easily the better answer here.

Comment: @Noldorin fyi: other answer is not only simpler, but it works more generally.

Comment: More general maybe, but this one is much clearer!

Answer (score 9):

Applying $\rm\color{#c00}{Euclid's}$ [Lemma:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) $\,\ b\mid an\overset{\color{#c00}{(a,\,b)\ {\bf =}\ 1}}\Longrightarrow\,b\mid n\,\overset{\large \times\ a\ }\Longrightarrow\,ab\mid an\quad  \small{\bf QED}$

**Remark** $ $ They're equivalent, i.e. conversely, this lcm property $\color{#0a0}{\rm L\ implies}$ Euclid's Lemma

$$ (a,b)=1,\ a\mid bc\ \Rightarrow\ a,b\mid bc\,\color{#0a0}{\stackrel{\large \rm L}\Rightarrow}\, ab\mid bc\,\Rightarrow\,a\mid c$$

Unlike proofs by Bezout, this proof by Euclid's Lemma works in UFDs which have no Bezout identity, e.g. polynomial rings like $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ and $\,\Bbb Q[x,y].\,$ The Bezout-based proofs essentially substitute inline into the above proof a Bezout-based proof of Euclid's Lemma, yielding essentially the following proof $\ a,b\mid c\,\Rightarrow\,ab\mid ac,bc\,\Rightarrow\,ab\mid (ac,bc) = (a,b)c = c\ $ in gcd (or ideal) language (compare [various forms of Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242)).

There are many useful properties known  equivalent to Euclid's Lemma over arbitrary domains, e.g. see the end of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/164589/78535) for a handful, and some closely related gcd properties.