# $f(x)$ is still irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x) \in K[x]$ an irreducible polynomial of $K[x]$ of degree $n$.

Let $K\leq F$ a field extension with $[F:K]=m$.

If $(n,m)=1$ show that $f(x)$ stays irreducible also as a polynomial of $F[x]$.

Could you give me some hints how to show this??

Comment: Let $\alpha$ be a zero of $f$ in some extension of $K$. Consider $K(\alpha)$ and $F(\alpha)$.

Comment: Do you mean that $a$ is algebraic over $K$??

Comment: $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$ since it is by assumption a zero of $f$.

Comment: Ok... Can we use that $$Irr(a,F) \mid Irr(a,K) \Rightarrow deg Irr(a,F) \leq deg Irr(a,K) $$ Or does this not stand??

Comment: That doesn't help. You need to use that $\gcd(\deg f, [F:K]) = 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer If I may ask, are you typing an answer?

Comment: @GitGud You may ask, and no, I'm not typing an answer. Go ahead and give a good hint if you wish.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you explain me how I could use that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$ and let $m_\alpha(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$.

It's easy to conclude that $n=\deg\left(m_\alpha(x)\right)=[K(\alpha)\colon K]$.

It holds that $K\preceq K(\alpha)\preceq F(\alpha)$ and $K\preceq F\preceq F(\alpha)$.

Since all these extensions are finite it follows that

$$\begin{align}
[F(\alpha)\colon K]&=[F(\alpha)\colon K(\alpha)]\overbrace{[K(\alpha)\colon K]}^{n},\\ 
[F(\alpha)\colon K]&=[F(\alpha)\colon F]\underbrace{[F\colon K]}_{m}.
\end{align}$$

From $\gcd(m,n)=1$, it follows that $mn$ divides $[F(\alpha)\colon K]$ and consequently $[F(\alpha)\colon K]\ge mn$ which in turn implies that $$m[F(\alpha)\colon F]=[F(\alpha)\colon K]\ge mn.$$ Thus $[F(\alpha)\colon F]\ge [K(\alpha)\colon K]$.

Given this inequality, I'll let you think how to relate it to certain minimal polynomials.

Comment: Could you explain me why it follows that $mn$ divides $[F(a):K]$ when $\gcd(m,n)=1$ ??

Comment: @MaryStar It's a typical elementary number theory result. $\forall a,b,c((\gcd(a,b)=1\land a|c\land b|c)\implies ab|c)$. See for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407540/if-gcda-b-1-and-a-and-b-divide-c-then-so-does-ab).

Comment: Oh, I see... So, does $$[F(a):F] \geq [K(a):K]$$ mean that $$deg Irr(a,F) \geq deg Irr(a,K)$$ ??

Comment: @MaryStar Exactly.

Comment: In that way do we conclude that the minimal polynomial at both case, over $K$ and over $F$, is the same??

Comment: Yes, that too.${}$

Comment: Why does this stand?? I got stuck right now...

Comment: When we have that $deg Irr(a,F) \geq degIrr(a,K)$, why does it follows that the minimal polynomial at both case, over K and over F, is the same??

Comment: That follows from what you wanted to prove initially, that is that $f(x)$ (or equivalently $m_\alpha(x)$) is irreducible over $F$.

Comment: How have we proven that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$ ??

Comment: If $f(x)$ was $F$-reducible, then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ would have degree smaller than $\deg(f(x))=n=[K(\alpha)\colon K]$, contradicting the last inequality.

Comment: I understand!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)