# If $a, b \mid c \text { and } \gcd(a, b) = d, \text { then } ab \mid cd $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

$a \mid c \implies c = ak \text {  and  } b \mid c \implies c = bj.$

$ak + bj = 2c = d \implies c \mid d.$

$d \mid a \implies a = dj.$

$c = ak = d(jk) \implies d \mid c.$

So, $c = d.$

$a \mid c \text {  and  } b \mid c \implies ab \mid cc \implies ab \mid cd.$

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Apply [this very standard fact](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407540/if-gcda-b-1-and-a-and-b-divide-c-then-so-does-ab) to $a \mid c$ and $(b/d) \mid c$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake:

$$ak+bj = 2c = d$$

I agree, since $ak=bj=c$, that $ak+bj=2c$, but why would $2c$ be equal to $\gcd(a,b)?$

Comment: I thought $ak + bj = d$ by Bezout. Do we need to choose different letters for that like $an + bm = d$?

Comment: @user263390 Of course. The $j,k$ given by Bezout are in general not the same $j,k$ as the ones given by the fact that $a|c$.

Comment: @ 5xum, $ax + by = d \to cax + cby = cd$. Since $a \mid c, a \mid cd \text { and } b \mid c \to b \mid cd.$ Then $ab \mid (cd)(cd). $ Am I going in the right direction with this?