# Showing that if $(a,b)=1$ and if $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ then $ab \mid c$, in GCD domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility, integral-domain, gcd-and-lcm

Is there a proof for the problem below?

> $R$ is a commutative, integral domain with unity in which for each pair $a,b\in R$, g.c.d. $(a,b)$ exists. I want to show that if $(a,b)=1$ and if $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ then $ab \mid c$.

In a [Bézout domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain) we can apply Bézout's identity as they do [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407540/if-gcda-b-1-and-a-and-b-divide-c-then-so-does-ab).

Is there a way to proceed without using Bézout's identity?

Comment: Presumably, you want without unique factorization, too. It follows from unique factorization.

Comment: Yes, $R$ isn't a UFD as stated

Comment: Well, no, you didn't state that. There are plenty of UFDs without Bezout, for example.

Comment: Apologies, I meant that in the question $R$ is defined in such a way that it isn't necessarily a UFD.

Comment: Is there a reason you believe it is true in this conditions? Like, was it a problem in a book?

Comment: Yes, it's from Bhattacharya, Jain, Nagpaul's "Basic Abstract Algebra". I should also note that the problem doesn't explicitly say that one can't use Bézout. Just the way that $R$ has been defined means we can't.

Comment: Okay, it's just a weirdly stated problem, so I thought it might have been a conjecture from you. The problem specifically mentions without Bézout's, but the assumptions are much weaker than that - the ring only needs a gcd, so there are lots of theorems weaker than Bézout's that are being excluded, as well.

Comment: I edited your problem statement to make it clear that by "without using Bézout" you are limiting the hypotheses, not the possible approaches to a proof (the first is easily quantifiable, but the second is not and often leads to confusion on the part of answerers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user26857's comment on Kishor J's answer makes clear, the important point is showing that for any $a,b,c$ we have $(ca,cb)=c(a,b)$.

Since we are in an integral domain, we have the following:

> If $xy\mid xz$, then $y\mid z$

Now observe that $c(a,b)$ divides both $ca$ and $cb$.  So $c(a,b)\mid (ca,cb)$.  We want to show that the opposite holds as well.

First observe that we have $c\mid c(a,b)\mid (ca,cb)$.  So we may write $(ca,cb)$ as $cg$ for some $g$.  Now we have:

- $c(a,b)\mid cg$ - so $(a,b)\mid g$.

It remains to show that $g\mid (a,b)$.  We note that:

- $gc=(ca,cb)\mid ca$ - so $g\mid a$
- $gc=(ca,cb)\mid cb$ - so $g\mid b$

Therefore, $g\mid (a,b)$, and so $g=(a,b)$ (up to multiplication by units).  We get that $(ca,cb)=c(a,b)$.

Now we need only observe that if $(a,b)=1$ then $(ca,cb)=c$, and the result is clear, since $ab\mid ca,cb$ if $a,b\mid c$.

Answer (score 0):

$ab \mid ca$ and $ab \mid cb$. Hence, $ab \mid (ca, cb)$. But $(ca, cb)$ is $c$ if $(a, b) = 1$. Therefore, $ab \mid c$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: The argument is correct, but proving $(ca,cb)=c(a,b)$ requires some care, and exactly this part is missing from your answer.