# How would you prove $ab|c$ knowing that $a|c$ and $b|c$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$?

Tags: number-theory

If $a|c$ and $b|c$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, prove that $ab|c$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you share what you've tried and explain what you're having trouble with?

Comment: I really don't know where to start right now

Comment: Do you know *any* results about numbers and gcds? Like factorization, or Bezout's theorem, or anything? Surely this wasn't phrased as an isolated exercise from the sky....

Comment: Yes. I know about what a GCD is and factorization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a$ and $b$ divide $c$, then so does $ab$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407540/if-gcda-b-1-and-a-and-b-divide-c-then-so-does-ab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a|c \implies c = ka$. $b|c \implies b|ka$ but since $gcd(a,b) = 1$, $b|ka \implies b|k \implies k = db \implies c = dba \implies ab|c$.