# If $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $a \mid c, b \mid c$, then $ab \mid c$

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation

For integers $a,b$ that are relatively prime to one another, we have $a \mid t$ and $b \mid t$. It should follow that $ab \mid t$, but I cannot manage to prove this. Here is as far as I was able to get.

> If $a \mid t$ and $b \mid t$, there exist integers $\beta, \alpha$ such that
> $$a \beta = t, \; b\alpha = t.$$
> Hence,
> $$(a\beta)(b\alpha) = (ab)(\beta \alpha )=t^2,$$
> so $ab \mid t^2$.

Why, though, does $ab$ divide $t^2$? Further, how do I even know that $ab \leq t$?

Another idea was to use Bezouts identity and assert the existence of integers $x$ and $y$ such that
$$ax + by = 1.$$
Multiply through by $\beta \alpha$ and reassociate:
$$(a\beta)(x\alpha) = (b\alpha)(y\beta) = \alpha \beta,$$
but this doesn't appear to help me.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407540/if-gcda-b-1-and-a-and-b-divide-c-then-so-does-ab - this might help as it is the same question.

Comment: Do you mean "why, though does $ab$ divide $t$"?

Answer (score 1):

The Bezout idea is good, try multiplying $ax+by=1$ by $t$ and using you factorisations of $t$ with $a$ and $b$.

Comment: So from $ax + by = 1$, I multiply through by $t$ to get $axt + byt = t$. Using the expressions for $t$, I get $(ax)(b\alpha) + (by)(a\beta) = t$. Reassociating gives $(ab)(x\alpha) + (ab)(y\beta) = t$. Since $ab$ divides each term on the left-hand side, it divides the right-hand side. Hence, $ab \mid t$. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.