# Show the given property about divisibility

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I want to show that if $m \geq 1, n \geq 1$ and $gcd(m,n)=1$, then $F_m F_n \mid F_{mn}$.

$F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

I have tried the following so far:

$$F_{mn}=F_{mn-1}+F_{mn-2}=2F_{mn-2}+F_{mn-3}=2(F_{mn-3}+F_{mn-4})+F_{mn-3}\\=3F_{mn-3}+2F_{mn-4}=\dots=\lambda F_{mn-\lambda}+(\lambda-1)F_{mn-(\lambda+1)}$$

Is it right so far? How can we continue in order to get the desired result?

Comment: Can you prove $F_m\mid F_{mn}$, $F_n\mid F_{mn}$ and $\gcd(F_m,F_n)=1$?

Comment: Could you give me a hint how we show these properties? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: @Evinda Follow the link in my answer for some proofs.

Answer (score 0):

By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60353/242) the $f_k$ are a *strong divisibility sequence* $\,\gcd(f_j,f_k) = f_{\large \gcd(j,k)}.\,$ In particular $\,f_j\mid f_{jk}$.  Thus $\,\gcd(f_m,f_n) = f_{\gcd(m,n)}\! = f_1\! = 1\,$ and $\,f_m,f_n\mid f_{mn}\Rightarrow\, {\rm lcm}(f_m,f_n) = f_m f_n\mid f_{mn}$

Comment: Above we used $\,\gcd(a,b)=1\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab.\ $ A proof is [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62066/242)